# Finding size i.e. number of non-null elements stored in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

**Purpose :** `Array.length` gives us storage initialized to array. But wanted to find out count of non-null elements stored in array out of total storage initialized. I know many approaches are possible but here question is related to approach which I used.

*Since `ArrayList` has a `size()` method which gives us count of actual elements stored regardless of total storage initialized.*

So, I thought of converting array to `ArrayList` and finding out the size. Hence I used `Arrays.asList(a).size()` as shown below:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int a[] = new int[10];
        a[0]=30;
        a[1]=100;
        a[2]=33;
        System.out.println((Arrays.asList(a)).size() );
    }
```

Strangely , it returns result as 1 regardless of the `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`.

Same steps if we do with `ArrayList` instead of Array gives us result 3:

```
{
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(20); 
    System.out.println(temp.size()); 
    temp.add(20); 
    temp.add(40); 
    System.out.println(temp.size()); 
}
```

Result is `0 2`.

**Question:** Should be agree that something is wrong with `asList` API of `Arrays` utitlity like bug or limitation?

**Remarks:**
Looking at internal implementation, I understand that `asList` invokes constructor of `ArrayList`:

```
  public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        size = elementData.length;
        .....
  }
```

It again invokes the collection's `toArray`. But then not sure why we are getting answer as 1 since `elementData.length` should have stored in size value `10`?

Comment: What does "Same steps if we do with ArrayList instead of Array gives us result 3." mean? How do you do those other steps? Where do you use Array?

Comment: When i said Same steps, i meant following which gives result 0 and 2 :                                
   List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
   System.out.println(temp.size());
   temp.add(20);
   temp.add(40);
  System.out.println(temp.size());

Comment: "Strangely , it returns result as 1 regardless". No, it returns 10. Primitives can't be null. Primitive arrays are automatically zeroed out. Zero is not null.

Comment: Please edit your question with that code and fix the typos that make it very difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 1 because `Arrays.asList(int[] a)` returns `List<int[]>`, not `List<Integer>`.
The way you're using method `asList()` is incorrect. If you would like to get `List<Integer>` instead, you should pass the contents of array to method `asList()` one by one.
`List<Integer> list = Array.asList(30, 100, 33);`
There is no direct method to convert an array into `List` on the fly

Comment: agree that "no direct method to convert an array into List" and the above is a wrong usage of asList.

Comment: @MadPhysicist right! I didn't follow Java 8. OP, for direct conversion, please refer to the link provided

Comment: In addition to MadPhysicist's input, if you only want to know the number of elements in your array A; just use the count function of the stream API: `Arrays.stream(<your array>).count()`.

Answer (score 3):

There are three very different concepts that you are somehow attempting to equate here.

First there's `null` elements in a list or array. `null` is a perfectly valid value to have in either. It is not the same as being uninitialized. In fact, arrays of any non-primitive type are explicitly initialized to `null` by default.

Then there are unused elements in a list. When you do

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(20);
a.add(null);
```

you will have a `List` of size 1. `null` is a totally valid reference to stick in a list, and the capacity has nothing to do with the size. The 20 you passed to the constructor is just a hint not to reallocate memory until you've inserted 20 actual elements into the list. Those 19 other elements are not `null`. They literally don't exist.

Third, there is the issue of primitive arrays. When you create a primitive array, it will have a fixed length and every element contains a valid value. By default, arrays are zeroed out with `false`, `0`, `0L`, `0.0f`, `0.0`, or whatever is appropriate for the type. Your code creates an array with three non-zero elements and seven zeros. Primitives are not references, so can never be `null`. Even if they could, making a `List` from a 10 element array would give you a size of 10.

Your attempt at creating an `ArrayList` is in no way equivalent to applying `Arrays.asList()`, even if that were to work. Creating a list and adding three elements to it will make a list of size three. On top of that, keep in mind that a `List` can *only* hold references, in your case to the boxed type `Integer`. An `Integer` reference can be `null` and still be a valid list item, but can't be unboxed into a primitive value.

Finally, you can't convert an array of primitives into a list using [`asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). `asList` accepts varargs, rather than a single list, which is why you always end up with one element list. The problem here is actually that you have a list of primitives: an array of references would be expanded just fine. An alternative in Java 8 is

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice the explicit boxing operation. The size of your list will still be 10, not 3.

Reference: [How to convert int[] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073919/2988730)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to get `List` from `Array`...!!!
Yes above sentence is partially correct.
If your array is of primitive type the it creates an List containing whole array as first element of newly created List.

Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[10];
    a[0] = 30;
    a[1] = 100;
    a[2] = 33;
    List list = Arrays.asList(a);
}
```

[image: List if int Array]

But if your array is of any reference type then it create with each element of passed array as a list element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object a[] = new Object[10];
    a[0] = 30;
    a[1] = 100;
    a[2] = 33;
    List list = Arrays.asList(a);
}
```

[image: List Of Objects]

That's why in your case it shows only one element in size.

This behavior is because of implementation of `asList()` which calls `ArrayList` constructor directly.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Integer a[] = new Integer[10];
        a[0]=30;
        a[1]=100;
        a[2]=33;
        //List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).size() );
    }
}
```

Output

> 10

Use wrapper classes, and there is your solution. Streams aren't quite performant as you expect (as of now).