# Is there any function to perform Circular Left Shift in an array between index i and index j (both inclusive) by in java

Tags: java, arrays, function

I want to perform a circular left shift in an array between index i and index j (both inclusive).

For example : Consider array A such as,

```
int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

If I want to perform circular left shift in the given array A between 0 (index i) and 2 (index j), the output is :

```
A = {2, 3, 1, 4, 5}
```

Is there any inbuilt function in java that can perform this type of operation.

I'm not asking about how to circular left shift an array n times. My question is to circular left shift some of the elements within an array as I have showed through the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a builtin function for it: [`Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))

For example,

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(A).subList(i, j+1), -1);
```

Update:

This does not work directly for primitive arrays because `Arrays.asList` does not do boxing for you. You need to create an `Integer[]` or `List<Integer>` somehow, which does not have very elegant way to do.

Comment: This function is giving out of bounds exception when used on integer array but works fine on a string array

Comment: @meisner97 This is because `Arrays.asList` does not work for primitive type arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java.

Answer (score 0):

For collections there are numerous manipulations available.
For arrays the class `Arrays` provides `copyOfRange` and other methods,
but nothing for an in-situ operation as desired. You can do:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
final int lwb = 0;
final int upb = 2;
```

with a lambda:

```
int alwb = a[lwb];
Arrays.setAll(a, i -> 
    i < lwb || i > upb ? a[i]
    i < upb -> a[i+1] : alwb
);
```

Or best:

```
int alwb = a[lwb];
System.arraycopy(a, lwb + 1, a, lwb, upb - lwb - 1);
a[upb] = alwb;
```