# How to convert short[] into List<Short> in Java with streams?

Tags: java, type-conversion, java-stream

I figured I could extrapolate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073919/3014199) but I can't

I can of course do

```
short[] shortarray = {0,1,2};
List<Short> shortList = new ArrayList<Short>();
for (Short s : shortarray) {
    shortList.add(s);
}
```

But I'm wondering how to do it with streams.

```
List<Short> shortList = Arrays.stream(shortarray).boxed()
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

doesn't work for example but yields `The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (short[])`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not

```
IntStream.range(0, shortarray.length)
         .mapToObj(s -> shortarray[s])
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why `mapToObj` and not `mapToInt` (or plain `map`)? using an `IntStream` instead of `Stream<Integer>` should be preferable in almost all situations when one is handling primitive ints or shorts.

Comment: `mapToInt` finally collect a `List<Integer>` instance, not a `List<Short>`.

Comment: @Polygnome I believe you have a point, but the OP is collecting elements into a `List<Short>`, so boxing can't be avoided.

Comment: @Polygnome “in almost all situations”, except when the task is to produce a `List<Short>`. Not that I ever encountered such a need in real life…

Answer (score 1):

As to why it does not work with a primitive short[]:

there is no Stream type of short. Streams only work for non primitive types or with 
*IntStream, LongStream, and DoubleStream*.

For it to work you would have to convert your shorts to a datatype with a compatible Stream, for example Short, or maybe to int for an IntStream (see ernest_k's answer).

Comment: Yes, you can not cast it, but you can convert each entry. I clarified that in an edit. I feel the "why" is  also important  for an answer and should be included.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can convert short array into a collection.

1. Convert short to Short object array
2. Use Arrays.asList method to convert Short[] into List and then iterate over them using streams.

See below sample code,

```java
Short[] shortarray = {0,1,2};
List<Short> shortList1 = Arrays.asList(shortarray);
shortList1.stream().forEach(aShort -> {System.out.println(aShort);});`
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: OP wants to convert `short[]` not `Short[]`

Comment: Actually, `Arrays` class only considers int, long, double or any Object types as parameters at the moment. So simple answer is "not possible" at the moment as short as parameter to the stream method of Arrays class.
Note: My opinion realted to Arrays.stream param support is valid until java 1.8 from my doc review.