# Why list of objects throws an exception when trying to update it's value?

Tags: java, arrays, list, unboxing

Why the following code throws ArrayStoreException on line 3:

```
int[] ar = {2, 4};
List list = Arrays.asList(ar);
list.set(0, 3);
```

Unboxing should be performed here from Integer to int but it doesn't.

Comment: [How to convert int array into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming that `Arrays.asList(ar)` creates a `List<Integer>`, but that's wrong.
`Arrays.asList(int[])` creates a `List<int[]>`, and setting an element of type `int` in that array explains the `ArrayStoreException` (saving an `int` in an `int[]` array).

If you want a `List<Integer>` with the same code, declare `ar` as `Integer[]`. This is probably another lesson to [avoid using raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)s (because the compiler would have prevented this runtime exception, had `List<Integer>` been used as the data type of `list`)

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes I expected that auto boxing should be performed and array of primitives transfers to array of wrappers.