# How to convert to "filter" from for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, filter, stream

I have a simple for loop
and I want to change it into a statement using filter

```java
for (int lotto_num: lottos) {
    if (lotto_num == 0) {
        unknown_count++;
    }
    
    for (int win_num : win_nums) {
        if (lotto_num == win_num) {
            count ++;
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible? I dont't really know how to use filter and stream.

Comment: Do you have example values for the variables `lottos` and `win_nums`? Can you show them?

Comment: Hint: *I have a simple for loop* is not quite correct, you have 2 for loops of which one is even nested. That's not really *simple* anymore…

Comment: `.filter()` is used to remove specific elements from a stream/collection. Your logic doesn't seem to be filtering. It produces two separate values that aren't attached to any specific element in the collection.

Comment: lottos = [44, 1, 0, 0, 31, 25] , win_nums = [31, 10, 45, 1, 6, 19]

Comment: @honey_bee What exactly your code should do? Count the number of intersections of `win_nums` and `lottos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Java's Stram API you should firstly convert your `int[]` arrays `win_nums` and `lottos` to `List<Integer>`.

It can be done this way:

```
List<Integer> win_nums_list = IntStream.of(win_nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> lottos_list= IntStream.of(lottos).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now we can use Stream API to get the desired result.

```
int count = win_nums_list.stream().filter(win_num -> lottos_list.contains(win_num)).count();

int unknown_count = lottos_list.stream().filter(lotto -> lotto== 0).count();
```

with adding imports to the beginning of your code:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: Oh I need to convert array to List. Is there a way using Arrays.stream() ~ ? (Just curiosity)

And I really appreciate you for letting me know. :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've edited my answer and presented you the way to do it with Stream API

Comment: See here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you !! I hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: @honey_bee if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. See here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work