# Java : convert List of Bytes to array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Trying to solve what should be a simple problem.  Got a list of Bytes, want to convert it at the end of a function to an array of bytes.

```
final List<Byte> pdu = new ArrayList<Byte>();
....
return pdu.toArray(new byte[pdu.size()]);;
```

compiler doesn't like syntax on my `toArray`.  How to fix this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like it, because `byte[]` isn't `Byte[]`.

What you can do is use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(wrapperCollection)`:

```
Byte[] bytes = pdu.toArray(new Byte[pdu.size()]);
return ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes);
```

If you can't use commons-lang, simply loop through the array and fill another array of type `byte[]` with the values (they will be automatically unboxed)

If you can live with `Byte[]` instead of `byte[]` - leave it that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)  I had not seen ArrayUtils.toPrimitive before, quite useful.

Comment: I do not like the solution of ArrayUtils. There has to be out of box solution for Java 8.

Comment: To use this lib in Android, put this in Gradle of App: implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6'

Answer (score 32):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s method [Bytes.toArray(Collection<Byte> collection)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#toArray(java.util.Collection)).

```
List<Byte> list = ...
byte[] bytes = Bytes.toArray(list);
```

This saves you having to do the intermediate array conversion that the Commons Lang equivalent requires yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Mainly, you cannot use a primitive type with `toArray(T[])`.

See: [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java).
This is the same problem applied to integers.

Answer (score 1):

try also [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/) ([check this revision](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/changeset/cea42757d873)):

```
import static com.humaorie.dollar.Dollar.*
...

List<Byte> pdu = ...;
byte[] bytes = $(pdu).convert().toByteArray();
```