# Converting Object[]arrayInteger to an int[] arrayInt

Tags: java, console

Is it possible to convert and Object[]array to and integer Array.

The reason I am asking is because I added integers to an ArrayList and then converted this into and Object[]array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Object[] arrayNumbers = list.toArray();
```

Which would be the best way of getting this into and int[]array?
All I need to do is to sort these numbers. Can I sort *all* my numbers in this arraylist without converting it into an int[]array?

Kind regards

Comment: "It depends how the sort is being done". (No, it is *not* required to have an `int[]` to sort a collection of integer objects; at the very least Integer implements Comparable.)

Comment: sorting is a different thing than converting a List<Integer> into a int[] array. And the latter was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706470/convert-integer-list-to-int-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing this:

```
Integer[] arrayNumbers = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

If you just want to sort, simply use `Collections.sort(list)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method instead of all the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the list of integers in the variable list.

Iterate over list and keep a track of the index and add array[index] = i:

Algorithm not Java code, I'll leave that to you:

```java
int index;

for (index =0; index <= list.Count(); index++) {
  array[index] = list[index];
}
```

Comment: @adarshr did you event read my answer? I clearly state it's the algorithm not Java code.....why downvote?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. Reverted back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code to sort your values

```
 Arrays.sort(arrayNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort()`

```
Collections.sort(list);
```