# Convert List<Integer> to int[]

Tags: java, arrays, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

What's the easiest way to convert a List to int[]?

list.toArray(new int[list.size()]) fails on a typecast error (Integer[] is not a int[]).

I could do it manually, I'm asking if there's an nicer way.

```
public static int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> list) {
  int[] result = new int[list.size()];
  for (int x : list) result.add(x); // assume no nulls
  return result;
}
```