# how to convert Vector<Integer> to an int[]?

Tags: java, vector, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

Is there some method to convert a Vector< Integer> to an int[]?

Thanks

Comment: `Vector<int>` can't (and doesn't) exist in Java.

Comment: Thank you Joachim Sauer. Vector<Integer> does exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) will do the conversion for you. Check the link for the javadoc of all the methods `Vector` has. This will be the boxed `Integer`, not `int`, but you can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] sl = (Integer[]) myVector.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector uses objects and not primary types. so you can only convert to an Object[], to convert to a primary type array you'd have to use an additional step.

with no further comments on what's the point of your code, I would say that Integer[] would acomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to copy a vector into an `int[]`

```
Vector<Integer> vector = ....
int count = 0, ints[] = new int[vector.size()];
for(int i: vector) ints[count++] = i;
```