# How to (efficiently) convert int[] to Integer[]?

Tags: java

Is there any direct way to convert int array to Integer array with out looping element by element.

Brute force way will be

```
int [] a = {1,2,3};
Integer [] b = new Integer[a.length];
for(i =0; i<a.length; i++)
    b[i]= i;
```

Is there any direct way with out traveling the entire array?

Comment: No, you will need to bite the bullet and travel the entire array.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java you might find some ways that suit you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've found the "only" way to do it using pure Java.  I prefer to make the Integer construction explicit, via

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
Integer[] b = new Integer[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = Integer.valueOf(a[i]);
}
```

Note that Apache has some utilities in Apache Lang, which basically do the same thing; however, the call looks more like

```
Integer[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(oldArray);
```

Of course, if you don't include the Apache libraries, you could write your own static function to make the code look pretty (if that's your concern).

Answer (score 5):

There's noting built in JDK but if you have apache commons, you could use

[`Integer[] ArrayUtils.toObject(int[] array)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

There are third-party libraries which will do the dirty work for you, but they're just going to loop under the covers.

E.g. with [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html):

```
int[] primitives = {1,2,3};
List<Integer> boxed = Ints.asList(primitives);
Integer[] boxedArray = Ints.asList(primitives).toArray(new Integer[]);
```

They don't give a one-method conversion presumably because you probably shouldn't be using arrays anyway but rather a `List`.

Comment: @Edwin: Guava is a Java library.

Comment: sorry, mistook it for one of the Java-like languages instead of the library it is.

Answer (score 2):

That's really the only way. When you're doing b[i] = i Java is auto unboxing your int to Integer. However that doesn't work when going from an int-array to an Integer-array.