# Android/Java: how to add array to array

Tags: java, android

I have five arrays.

```
int Circle_list[] = { Color.BLACK, 20, 20, 50 };
int Rect_list[] = { Color.BLUE, 80, 50, 115, 150 };
int Tri_list[] = { Color.RED, 190, 210, 150, 230, 140, 270 };
int mixColor[];
int mixCoor[];
```

Now, I want to add the first element(color) from `Circle_list[]`, `Rect_list[]` and `Tri_list[]` into `mixColor[]`. And add all rest numbers into `mixCoor[]`.

How can I do that? Does for loop available for this?

Comment: The first three arrays are invalid - they contain a mix of `Color` objects and `int` , in Java all the elements in an array must be of the same type (although some polymorphism is allowed, but that's another matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// if you really want to use primitives instead of ArrayLists, this will work:

```
int mixColor[] = { Circle_list[0], Rect_list[0], Tri_list[0] };
int mixCoor[] = new int[Circle_list.length + Rect_list.length + Tri_list.length - 3];

int i, j=0;

for(i=1; i<Circle_list.length; ++i, j++) {
    mixCoor[j] = Circle_list[i];
}
for(i=1; i<Rect_list.length; ++i, j++) {
    mixCoor[j] = Rect_list[i];
}
for(i=1; i<Tri_list.length; ++i, j++) {
    mixCoor[j] = Tri_list[i];
}
```

// OR more general solution:

```
j = 0;
int[][] shapes = {Circle_list, Rect_list, Tri_list};
for (int[] shape : shapes) {
    for(i=1; i<shape.length; ++i, j++) {
        mixCoor[j] = shape[i];
    }
}
```

// If you want to use ArrayLists instead, see also: [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

I do prefer `ArrayList`, let say in your case it would be like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listCircle = ...
ArrayList<Integer> listRect = ...
ArrayList<Integer> listTri = ...
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> storage = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
storage.add(listCircle);
storage.add(listRect);
storage.add(listTri);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mixColor[] = { Circle_list[0], Rect_list[0], Tri_list[0] };
```

As for `mixCoor` (I would also rename your identifier, they're too similar) - does order matter?  If not then just loop through the other tables, check if the value of the current index (the counter in the loop) is valid, and if it is, add it to your new table.

Comment: `System.arrayCopy` tends to be faster for large arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html