# Adding double value to List<double[]>

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android app, and I need to save the double value(BodySize) to a file in a form of List to draw a graph. Actually this code was in form of 'List' and I tried to change it into 'List'. But it makes error in 'list.add(BodySize)'. How can I fix this problem?

```
 public static void updateFile(double BodySize) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

            try{
                List<double[]> list = getDoubles();
                list.add(BodySize);
                fos = new FileOutputStream("user_data.txt");
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(list);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    oos.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        public static List<double[]> getDoubles() {

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            List<double[]> newList = new ArrayList<double[]>>();
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream("user_data.txt");
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                newList = (ArrayList<double[]>) ois.readObject();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                try {
                    fis.close();
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return newList;
        }
```

Comment: The list contain double array and you are trying to add double value. Try to implement according to `Kazekage Gaara's` answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ArrayList<double[]>()` creates a list of arrays of doubles, not a list of doubles. The list itself is an array (of variable length), so just use :

```
List<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: Is 'List<Double>' the same as 'double[]'?

Comment: An ArrayList<Double> is an array which automatically grows as you add more elements. A simple double[] array has a fixed length which cannot be changed.

Comment: no, the List<Double> is a list of Double Objects and the latter is an array of doubles (mind the cases)

Comment: I have to use that values to draw a line graph using AchartEngine. In its demo code, it uses double[] type as values to draw a graph. Can I still use List<Double> in this case?

Comment: It is possible to convert a List<Double> to double[], read this question for more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java

Comment: You're welcome. But don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you (click on the check mark on the left). Please do the same for your other answers by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Bodysize is a double, and the list is of type double [] (array of double)

Comment: I'm not familiar with types such as list, double[] and Double. What I want to do is save the double values(BodySize) in a form of array[]. What should I do?

Comment: Then first learn about them before implement such complex program. And also nobody knows whats in `user_data.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<double[]> list = getDoubles();
        list.add(BodySize);
```

`BodySize` is of type `double` whereas `List<double[]>` expects `double[]`

Comment: Now I can understand what was my mistake. I want to save double values(BodySize) in a form ou double[]. Please give me some help.