# find longest linked lists in an array of linked lists

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, linked-list

I have an array of linked lists (an adjacency list) most of the lengths of the linked lists are 4 but there are some that will randomly have more than that. My goal is to go through the array and find the ones that are more than length 4 (thats the easy part) then add the index's to an array so something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    if(sWorld[i].length > 4)
         //add i to an array
         // then sort the array
```

couldnt really figure out how to do this. i tried to add to a inked list then linked list toArray() but then it was messing up. i just dont really know how to add the 'i' point in my sWorld array to say the first position in the new array im going to use for the ones that are grater than size 4.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDITED TO CLARIFY A BIT**

i need the indexes of the the locations that are size > 4, but then i want to know which of those indexes that i get have the greatest size. Maybe i wasnt 100% clear in my op, but basically im trying to find which of the 1000 indexes in the array have the most connections (the longest linked list) make sense?

I want to know the top 10 connected indexes of the array (aka which 10 have the greatest size of linked list)

Comment: not to sure how that would work. never really worked with them

Comment: I suggest to use ArrayList of linkedlists..

Comment: @Mido a `Map<Integer, List<SomeClass>>` backed up by a `HashMap<Integer, List<SomeClass>>`.

Comment: is your goal to get an array of the lists with more than 4 elements or an array of the indexes of lists with more than 4 elements?

Comment: How do you want them sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ArrayList` to store the indexes:

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    if (sWorld[i].length > 4) {
         //add i to a list (not an array yet)
         indexes.add(i);
    }
    ...
}
// then sort the list
// not necessary, as indexes are inserted in the right order, but if you must...
// Collections.sort(indexes);

// and, if you need an array instead of a list
Integer[] indexesArray = indexes.toArray(new Integer[indexes.size()]);
```

A `List`, or an `ArrayList`, work as variable-length arrays. Though not as efficiently as an actual array.

As seen above, there is no need to sort the array later, but, if you must, you can use `Collections.sort()`.

Also, if you must have an `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`, please check: [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

**Update:**

As you want to know the size and index of the bigger arrays, it's a whole new problem. Below is a working code that deals with it.

Basically, everytime you find an array with size larger than 4, you add a pair `(index, size)` to the list. This list is then ordered by size, in descending order.

**At the end of the `main()` method, an array is created (`int[] topTenIndexes`) which contains the indexes of the 10 biggest arrays (the indexes are presented in descending order of it's array's length). The result is -1 when there weren't enough big (length > 4) arrays.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArrayIndexAndSize> indexes = new ArrayList<ArrayIndexAndSize>();

        int[][] sWorld = {{1},{2,5,5,5,5},{3,6,6,6,6,6}};
        for (int i = 0; i < sWorld.length; i++){
            if (sWorld[i].length > 4) {
                 // add a pair (index, size) to the list
                 indexes.add(new ArrayIndexAndSize(i, sWorld[i].length));
            }
            //...
        }
        // then sort the list by array SIZE, in descending order
        Collections.sort(indexes);
        // Print it!
        System.out.println(indexes);
        /* output:
        "[[Array index: 2; Array size: 6], [Array index: 1; Array size: 5]]"
         */

        // Generating an array with the top ten indexes
        int[] topTenIndexes = new int[10];
        Arrays.fill(topTenIndexes, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size() && i < 10; i++) {
            topTenIndexes[i] = indexes.get(i).index;
        }
        // Print it
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(topTenIndexes));
        /* output: [2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] */
    }

    public static class ArrayIndexAndSize implements Comparable<ArrayIndexAndSize> {
        public int index;
        public int size;
        public ArrayIndexAndSize(int index, int size) {
            this.index = index;
            this.size = size;
        }
        /* Order by size, DESC */
        /* This is called by Collections.sort and defines the order of two elements */
        public int compareTo(ArrayIndexAndSize another) {
            int thisVal = this.size;
            int anotherVal = another.size;
            return -(thisVal<anotherVal ? -1 : (thisVal==anotherVal ? 0 : 1));
       }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[Array index: "+index+"; Array size: "+size+"]"; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No need to sort the `indexes` list -- they're automatically sorted by the way the list was populated!

Comment: You are correct! Changed the code. I guess I'm getting old :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is there an way to do the sort based on sWorld.size() ? because yes i need the indexes of the the locations that are size > 4, but then i want to know which of those indexes that i get have the greatest size. Maybe i wasnt 100% clear in my op, but basically im trying to find which of the 1000 indexes in the array have the most connections (the longest linked list) make sense? thanks again for your help man!

Comment: Please check again now. It is final.

Comment: wow thanks man, pretty impressive, one quick question though. Whats the .index at the end of the line             topTenIndexes[i] = indexes.get(i).index;    for? because it wont accept that in my program?

Comment: It contains the `index` value of the top ten largest arrays. I edited the code a bit (put `public` before `int index;`, `int size;` and `static class ArrayIndexAndSize`), hopefully, it will solve your program's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `LinkedList<?>[] sWorld` (fill the type you're using in for `?`), then do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<sWorld.size(); i++) {
    if (sWorld[i].size > 4) {
        listOfLists.add(i);
    }
}
Comparator<Integer> sizeComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Integer.compare(sWorld[a].size(), sWorld[b].size());
    }
}
Collections.sort(listOfLists, sizeComparator);
```

Comment: OP wants a list of the indexes for the long lists, not a list of the long lists themselves.