# Java Integer[] to int[]

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have a List which I need to convert to an int array (int[])

Currently I am doing this:

```
List<Integer> filters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// add some elements to filters
int[] filteres = new int[filters.size()];
for(Integer i=0 ; i<filters.size(); i++) 
    filteres[i] = filters.toArray(
                  new Integer[filters.size()])[i].intValue();
```

I think this looks like a messy workaround and that should be somehow else to do this.
So is there a better way to make such conversion?

Comment: `filters.toArray(new Integer[filters.size()])[i]` - this is entirely unnecessary and wasteful; someone needs to learn to index into a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (alternatively, skip indexing entirely with an enhanced for loop)

Comment: Also, your title lies. The operation is List<Integer> to int[], not Integer[] to int[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified using the [List.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) from the List interface:

```
int[] filteres = new int[];
for(int i=0 ; i<filters.size(); i++) 
   //auto unboxing takes care of converting Integer to int for you, if it's not null.
    filteres[i] = filters.get(i);
```

Comment: The enhanced for loop would be a better choice (since it uses an iterator) as `get(int index)` can be slow for certain List implementations (LinkedList)

Answer (score 2):

See [How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java?rq=1) (which is a duplicate by all means; see [this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965289/2864740)).

However, for sake of discussion, consider this similar alternative and notes.

```
List<Integer> filters = getFilters();

// Arrays must be created with a size: the original code won't compile.
int[] ints = new int[filters.size()];

// Use an Enhanced For Loop if an index lookup into the source
// is not required; i is merely a result of needing to index the target.
int i = 0;
for(Integer filter : filters) {
    // Just use auto unboxing Integer->int; no need for intValue()
    ints[i++] = filter;
}
```

The original code is *terrible* because `filters.toArray(new Integer[filters.size()])[i]` creates a *new* array from the list each loop before the index operation. This makes the complexity O(n^2)+ just for the copy! While this can be fixed by replacing the offending expression with [`filters.get(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)), an indexing operation can be skipped entirely in this case.

Using an enumerable approach similar to shown above (i.e. with an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)) has the advantage that it will continue to work efficiently over source collections which are not fast-indexable such as a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). (Even using the `filters.get(i)` replacement, a LinkedList source collection would result in a O(n^2) complexity for the transformation - yikes!)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
filteres[i] = filters.toArray(
              new Integer[filters.size()])[i].intValue();
```

You can just retreive the element like this:

```
filteres[i] = filters.get(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] filteres = new int[filters.size()];
        for(int i =0;i<filters.size();i++){
            filteres[i]=filters.get(i);
        }
```