# how to convert from Object[] to int[]

Tags: java, vector, cosine-similarity

I want to pass `myVector` to another class (`Case.java`) but I get this    kind of error message. Type mismatch: **cannot convert from Object[] to int[]**. Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

**User.java**

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Process");

btnNewButton.setBounds(360, 296, 89, 23);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Integer a = (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
        Integer b = (comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
        Integer day = (comboBox_2.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
        ArrayList<Integer> myVector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myVector.add(a);
        myVector.add(b);
        myVector.add(day);

        Case ca = new Case();
        try {
            ca.addPlace(myVector);
            LoginGUI um = new LoginGUI();
            um.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Case.java**

```
public class Case {

    public Case() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void addPlace(ArrayList<Integer> h) {

        int vec1[] = h.toArray();
        int vec2[] = {2, 1, 3, 2};

        double cos_sim = cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Java8 this would be possible:

```
int[] vec1 =  h.stream().filter(t -> t != null).mapToInt(t -> t).toArray();
```

Comment: This may throw a NullPointerException. You need to either filter out null values, or handle them in the mapping function.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot convert `Object[]` to `int[]`. Those two classes are Horizontal.

If you want you can convert `Object[]` into `Integer[]` Wrapper class with Explicit **Down Casting**.

```
        Object[] obj ={10,30,20,100};
       Integer[] in = (Integer[]) obj;
```

Comment: This will not work. Gives `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;`

Answer (score 3):

Pass a new array to the `toArray` method. Like this:

```
Integer[] vec = h.toArray(new Integer[h.size()]);
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to perform manual conversion:

```
ArrayList<Integer> h = new ArrayList<>();
int[] result = new int[h.size()];
int index = 0;
for(int val:h){
    result[index++] =val; 
}
```

Of course, it could throw NullPointerException in case you have null-values in original ArrayList "h".

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not converting `Object[]` to `int[]`, what you are doing here is `ArrayList<Integer>` to `int[]`. Th error which you  are getting *cannot convert from Object[] to int[]* is because `Integer[]` is not directly convertible to `int[]`.

So this one is directly not possible with any method. But you can do it like :-

```
        int[] vec1= new int[h.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i : h){
            vec1[index] = i;
            index++;
        }
```

But if you can change your `int[] vec1` to `Interger[] vec1` then you can do like :-

```
 Integer[] vec1 =  h.toArray(new Integer[h.size()]);
```