# Converting ArrayList<Integer> into int[] won't work in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I have been developing a program where I have to convert an ArrayList into an int[]. I do not get any syntax errors when I run the code. However, when I print the int[] to see if it does work, it prints out a random string which is "[I@2a139a55" How can I fix this?

I cannot use an int[] from the start. This program HAS to convert an ArrayList into int[].

```
        ArrayList<Integer> student_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       student_id.add(6666);
       student_id.add(7888);    

       int[] student_id_array = new int[student_id.size()];
       for (int i=0, len = student_id.size(); i < len; i ++){
            student_id_array[i] = student_id.get(i);
       }
       System.out.println(student_id_array);
```

Comment: You cannot print an array directly. You have to use `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(student_id_array));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert List<Integer> to int\[\] in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out the reference to the array. Use `Arrays.toString(int[])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the converting your `ArrayList<Integer>` to `int[]` with one line in Java 8:

```
int[] student_id_array = student_id.stream().mapToInt(id -> id).toArray();
```

And if you want to output array's values instead of representation of your array (*like `[I@2a139a55`*) use `Arrays.toString()` method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(student_id_array));
```

Comment: Nice stream usage :D

Answer (score 0):

That because you are printing the memory address of that array.

try this :

```
   ArrayList<Integer> student_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   student_id.add(6666);
   student_id.add(7888);    

   int[] student_id_array = new int[student_id.size()];
   for (int i=0, len = student_id.size(); i < len; i ++){
        student_id_array[i] = student_id.get(i);
   }
   System.out.println(student_id_array[0]+" "+student_id_array[1]);
```

Output :

```
6666 7888
```

OR use `for-loop` if you populate the `ArrayList` later on.