# How to fix this error "can not cast java.lang.Integer to int"

Tags: java, android

I created two set of ImageViews Say ViewGroup A(has 26) and B(has 26);

&

also  26 Images named as  'a', 'b' ......... 'z'   i.e image a has A image

Step1: I load 26 images randomly to the Group B (26 Imageviews)
 and while loading I set the name of the Image in ImageView's tag (int value) i.e 97 for Image'a'

Step2 When user clicks the image  in the correct order A B C ... Z ,then image will move from Group B  to Group A Imageview 1, 2.... 26..

Here the below code does the second step2.....

Note:
currentText= 'a'

```
         // this method called in image onclick
    public void ImageClicked(View view) {
    int nameFromImagetag;
    char tag;
    ImageView ClickedImage = (ImageView) view;
    ImageView ImageViewInGroupA = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    nameFromImagetag = (int) ClickedImage.getTag();
    tag=(char) nameFromImagetag;


    if (tag == currentText) { 
        ImageViewInGroupA = (ImageView) findViewById(ImageViewGroupAIdList[PointerToGroupA]); 
           //Next line pops up error "can not cast java.lang.Integer to int"


             ImageViewInGroupA.setImageResource((int) ClickedImage.getTag());
        ClickedImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        ClickedImage.setTag(null);
        ClickedImage.setClickable(false);
        currentText = (char) ((int) currentText + 1);
        PointerToGroupA = PointerToGroupA + 1;
    }
```

}

04-05 09:55:22.674 5168-5168/com.example.android.myabc E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
04-05 09:55:28.074 5168-5168/com.example.android.myabc E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
04-05 09:56:36.444 5168-5168/com.example.android.myabc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x61
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
                                                                             at com.example.android.myabc.MainActivity.ImageClicked(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-05 09:56:37.234 1503-1503/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert List<Integer> to int\[\] in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java)

Comment: @Murali, you did not share the *exact* error message. Copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your tag is an `Integer` object and not an `int` primitive. This code checks that the object is of the correct type and gets the int value out of the Integer if it is valid (0 otherwise):

```
Object obj = ClickedImage.getTag();
nameFromImagetag = (obj instanceof Integer) ? ((Integer)obj).intValue() : 0;
```

Comment: An `Integer` should auto-unbox to `int`.

Comment: @chrylis you are correct. I used `intValue()` to explain exactly what is happening. `nameFromImagetag = (obj instanceof Integer) ? (Integer)obj : 0;` achieves the same result but is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Modified code below! ..........Hey Its working king ing ng.g..:)
```

Kindly Ignore the scraps.... :)

```
   public void ImageClicked(View view) {
    int nameFromImagetag,id=-1;
    Integer MyInt=null;
    char tag;
    Object MyObj=null; //changed
    ImageView ClickedImage = (ImageView) view;        
    ImageView ImageViewInGroupA = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    findViewById(ImageViewGroupBIdList[PointerToGroupA]);
    nameFromImagetag = (int) ClickedImage.getTag();
    tag=(char) nameFromImagetag;
    if (tag == currentText) {
        ImageViewInGroupA = (ImageView) findViewById(ImageViewGroupAIdList[PointerToGroupA]);


        MyObj=ClickedImage.getTag(); //changed
        id=((Integer)MyObj).intValue();  //changed

        id = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf((char) id), "drawable", getPackageName()); //changed

        ImageViewInGroupA.setImageResource(id);
        ClickedImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        ClickedImage.setTag(null);
        ClickedImage.setClickable(false);
        currentText = (char) ((int) currentText + 1);
        PointerToGroupA = PointerToGroupA + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Working Thanks Doron Yakovlev-Golani and all :)