# Find odd numbers between a closed range

Tags: java, algorithm

I am doing a code challenge where given two integers l and r, I have to print all the odd numbers between i and r (i and r inclusive). The function must return an array of integers denoting the odd numbers between l and r.

This is what I have so far

```
 static List<Integer> oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    if ((r > l) && (l >= 1) && (r <= 100000)) {
        for (int i = tmp; tmp < r; i++) {
            if (l % 2 == 0)
               l = l + 1;              
            list1.add(l);
            l = l + 2;
        }
    }
    return list1;
}
```

However, I received several errors like this

```
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
Your Output (stdout)
Output hidden
```

Any ideas for this?
on the QA of the challenge site, it seems related to Corner case problems.

Comment: these seem like custom messages. where are they in your code? I would recommend not to duplicate code. yes, you have to do a even check before adding, but you don't need to duplicate all the following code

Comment: @Stultuske I think these are the code challenge responses

Comment: Can you add link to challenge site ?

Comment: looks like you are excluding r. Besides, should you return an array or a List? It's unclear.

Comment: @Eran quite possibly that's the reason for the Compiler Message - error

Comment: if l = r = odd, I think you should add it to the list

Comment: why do you exclude negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, you're excluding `r` in your loop and are perhaps returning the wrong data structure?

Moreover, your code is doing way more than it needs to

- you only need one loop
- you don't need `tmp` at all - just modify `l`
- you don't need all the if/else blocks

I suggest the following:

```
static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    if (l % 2 == 0) l++;
    for(; l <= r; l += 2) {
        list1.add(l);
    }
    return list1.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray(); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945015/2554605
}
```

You can add back the `if ((r >= l) && (l >= 1) && (r <= 100000))` if it's needed based on challenge requirements, but I'm not that it's necessary (notice I have `r >= l` instead of just `r > l` to cover the case where `r == l`).

As well, if you really are allowed to return `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`, then just `return list1;` instead as you had it.

Comment: just a thought. so far as I can tell, the limits (inclusive) are l and r, but unless the requirement on that page is different compared to the one posted here, it's not stated which of the two is the upper, and which the lower limit.

Comment: @Stultuske I figure the `l` and `r` are self-explanatory due to their names. I suppose if it were generic `a` and `b` though, we could swap the values if `a > b` and keep our logic the same.

Comment: how are i and r self-explanatory? might be because I myself am not a native English speaker, but still ..

Comment: @Stultuske I believe it's `l`, not `i`. I know OP said `i` but it really doesn't make sense because he starts with `l`. And `l` is short for `left`; `r` is short for `right`. So `r` is upper bound is `l` is lower bound.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following code :

```
public static List<Integer> getOdd(int l, int r) {
    List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (l % 2 == 0)
        l++;
    while(l <= r) {
        odd.add(l);
        l += 2;
    }
    return odd;
}
```

Comment: seriously? why? first of all, it has to return an array, not a list, secondly, why would you want to compare all values to check if they are odd/even, if you can just get the first odd one, and add 2 each iteration, instead of re-checking every time?

Comment: I saw in @Yang 's example that he was returning a list.
And yeah you're right, it's better to get the first odd number and add 2.

Comment: Indeed, he returns a list. He also receives a compiler error message, which might very well be caused by returning a list.

Comment: I did edit my answer to avoid re-checking every time, but for the List I really don't know because he didn't specify anything.
Anyway thanks for your answers !

Comment: as his requirement description states: "The function must return an array of integers"

Answer (score 0):

this version should be working

```
 static List<int> oddNumbers(int l, int r)
    {
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
        if ((r > l) && (l >= 1) && (r <= 100000))
        {
            int tmp = l % 2 == 0 ? l + 1 : l;            
            for (int i = tmp; i < r; i += 2)
            {
                list1.Add(i);
            }

        }
        return list1;
    }
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. for starters: it returns a List

Comment: adds ToArray() to result, but it is algorithm question.

Comment: No. the question is: "where do my errors come from". just the title is limited to that

Comment: Array in this case is  overusing memory it might regard as error.  Or  only logical issues  should be noted?

Comment: depends on the requirements. If the requirements are: "return an array", chances are the result will be ran against a number of asserts to check whether it is an array, and whether result.length is the value they expect.

Comment: I got your point , thanks. But I hope it is site for sharing knowledge but not for red tape.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing by 2 and checking if the remainder is 0 or 1,
you can bitwise and with `1(&1)` and it will look like this
if `((number&1)==1)` then the number is odd, it reduce complexity.