# What does .stream().mapToInt(i -> i) mean in Java?

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
public int[] decompressRLElist(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer>ans = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < nums[i]; ++j) 
            ans.add(nums[i + 1]);
    return ans.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();`
```

I do not understand the last line.

Comment: Related? [How to convert List<Integer> to int[\] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960431), specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945015

Comment: I would prefer `return ans.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

In general `mapToInt` maps each item from a stream to `int`. It also creates an `IntStream` that has specialized methods for the primitive type `int`

In this specific case the method is used to convert `Integer` (The wrapper object) to an `int` the primitive type. With the `IntStream`it is possible to create an actual `int[]` instead of an `Integer[]`

It boils down to understanding the difference between primitive types and their wrappers. Especially autoboxing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html