# How can I mock this piece of code of Spring Boot using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

Consider:

```java
return attachmentList.stream().map(attachment -> {
    AttachmentBO attachmentBO = new AttachmentBO();
    attachmentBO.setId(attachment.getId());
    attachmentBO.setTitle(attachment.getName());
    attachmentBO.setType(attachment.getValue().get("type").toString());
    attachmentBO.setCreatorId(attachment.getAuditUserId());
    String[] filteredPermissionsForNote = this.filterPermissionCommand.filterPermissions(answer.getTopicId(), attachment.getAuditUserId(), topicDetails.getPermissions(), topicDetails.getEffectiveRoles(), true);
    attachmentBO.setPermissions(filteredPermissionsForNote);

    if (attachmentBO.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("URL")) {
        attachmentBO.setUrl(String.valueOf(attachment.getMediaInfo().get("url")));
    } else if (attachmentBO.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("FILE")) {
        attachmentBO.setSize((Double) attachment.getValue().get("size"));
    }

    return attachmentBO;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have mocked the attachmentList using Mockito, so I am getting the attachmentList. But how should I mock the remaining code? I have even mocked filterpermission.

Comment: 1) What are you trying to test? 2) Maybe just use predefined list instead of mocking it?

Comment: I am testing my controller so I am injecting this service in my controller the above code is of my service layer.

Comment: And what exactly you want to test: that service's method is called with proper argument or are you writing an integration test?

Comment: (Syntax highlighting here on Stack Overflow: Why does variable "`attachmentBO`" have a different colour in the declaration compared to where it is used? Why is it different for the (array) variable "`ret`" in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/)?)

Answer (score 0):

Do not mock the list elements. Instead mock one level higher to return you a *test list* instead.

To clarify:

```java
List<Attachment> attachmentList = List.of(RealAttachment1, RealAttachment2); // <-- Nothing is using Mockito here.

when(someMethodWhichReturnsAttachmentList()).thenReturn(attachmentList);
```

Then in your business logic:

```java
attachmentList = someMethodWhichReturnsAttachmentList(); // Mockito will return you the test list you created earlier.


// You will now map the test List elements, as in a normal business logic
return attachmentList.stream().map(attachment -> {
    AttachmentBO attachmentBO = new AttachmentBO();
    attachmentBO.setId(attachment.getId());
    attachmentBO.setTitle(attachment.getName());
    attachmentBO.setType(attachment.getValue().get("type").toString());
    attachmentBO.setCreatorId(attachment.getAuditUserId());
    String[] filteredPermissionsForNote = this.filterPermissionCommand.filterPermissions(answer.getTopicId(), attachment.getAuditUserId(), topicDetails.getPermissions(), topicDetails.getEffectiveRoles(), true);
    attachmentBO.setPermissions(filteredPermissionsForNote);

    if (attachmentBO.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("URL")) {
        attachmentBO.setUrl(String.valueOf(attachment.getMediaInfo().get("url")));
    } else if (attachmentBO.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("FILE")) {
        attachmentBO.setSize((Double) attachment.getValue().get("size"));
    }

    return attachmentBO;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The business logic will return the `List.of(attachments)` you created in your *test*, and run through them all, including `map/collect`.