# Java: Are there some quasi-standard APIs out there, which do int[] <-> Integer[] and similar?

Tags: java, arrays, api, primitive-types, boxing

I need to do lots of conversions between `primitivetype[]` and `boxedtype[]` (both directions).
*Such as: `Integer[] <-> int[]`, `Double[] <-> double[]`, ...*

I wanted to know, if there's some quasi-standards APIs out there, which provide such functionality, before I write such utility methods by myself.

*Java has [**8** primitive types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), so it would be quite a (copy-paste) work...*

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using primitive arrays instead of lists? Just curious

Comment: Primitive arrays are lots faster and more memory-efficient (think of operations on huge number matrices) ;)    
But to be able to generalize certain functionality, I also need boxed arrays.

Comment: I see. Probably using an initial size in the List big enough would make it as fast and efficient as bare arrays. After all, `ArrayList` for instance uses arrays as underlaying store.

Comment: Yes, it would be probably similarly fast, but not as memory efficient: boxed types are objects, each one of them has an overhead (compared to primitive types). Also, think of garbage collection: what is faster, freeing a fixed primitive array, or millions of objects? *(I would guess, it's quite a difference).*

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/java-convert-int-to-integer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java,

Comment: **Related? Yes. Close because of duplicate? No.** I asked specifically for an API, which "automates" the conversion process. Those questions (and their answers) address more a possible self-made implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

`ArrayUtils.toObject( primitive[] )`

and

`ArrayUtil.toPrimitive( wrapper[] )`

Comment: Ah, so it's Apache Commons Lang! I've looked only in Apache Commons Collections.

Comment: Yeah, Apache's layers of project hierarchy remind me of a Matryoshka doll.  It's can be quite hard to find things.

Comment: As a Russian, I may correct you: It's called Matryoshka ;)   
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll

Comment: "Matryoshka" is more common I think ;)

Comment: In spanish they are called ( well I do ) "Matrushka" .. :P cultural note.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've written a [LGPL3 library](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar), so it isn't stardard nor widely adopted, that try to addressing these problems:

```
Integer[] boxed = ... ;
int[] primitive = $(boxed).toIntArray();
```

and viceversa:

```
boxed = $(boxed).toArray();
```

But I'm hoping that you will appreciate some extra features like casting:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
int[] ints = $(bytes).toIntArray();
short[] shorts = $(bytes).toShortArray();
```

Comment: Not a fan of the jQuery-style do-everything global function.