# Passing an int[] to a generic method that takes a T[]

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int[] intarray = {1, 3, 6, 8, 2, 6};        
    String[] names = {"String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", "String6"};

    printMe(intarray);

}

public static <T> void printMe(T[] i){
    for(T x: i)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Why does compiling this code result in this error?

```
The method printMe(T[]) is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

If I do `printMe(names)` then it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert int\[\] to Integer\[\] in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)

Comment: Also related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because its array of `int` not of `Integer`, its expecting a class over there

Comment: thanks a lot. but what's the difference between int and Integer? Is Integer defined as `Integer Object` by the system (since I've not defined it)?

Comment: `int` is primitive data type, where `Integer` is class

Comment: `Integer` is [`java.lang.Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Comment: I mean is it defined by the system? (i don't remember defining an object name Integer)

Comment: yes it is included with standard lib. check http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Generics are meant for `Object`-based datatypes and not for `primitives`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Generics are meant for Object-based datatypes and not for primitives.
In the case of String array it is type casting to object type, in case int array automatically it is not casted to Object type, So either explicitely another method to be included or make it Integer.