# ArrayList with integers and user input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, menu, java.util.scanner

So I have a school assignment that I am stuck on and would like some guidance on how to approach it. The task is:

The purpose of this lab is to manipulate an ArrayList of integers. The assignment is to
write a program that:
1. Declares an ArrayList of integers.
2. Implements the following methods:
 A method that displays a menu. The menu should be displayed after each
completed menu selection.
1. Add elements
2. Add an element at a specific index
3. Remove an element at specific index
4. Show min, max, sum and average
5. Search
6. Exit

So I already have the code here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayList
{
    static int count;
    static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main()
    {
        int item=0;
        ArrayList numArray = new ArrayList();
        count=0;


        while (item !=6)
        {
            menu();
            item=kb.nextInt();
            if (item==1)
                addElements(numArray);
            //else if (item==2)
                //printArray(numArray);
        }

        System.out.println("Goodby!");

    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        System.out.println("1. Add Elements");
        System.out.println("2. Add an element at a specific index");
        System.out.println("3. Remove an element at a specific index");
        System.out.println("4. Show min, max, sum and average");
        System.out.println("5. Search");
        System.out.println("6. Exit");
        System.out.print(": ");
    }

    public static void addElements(ArrayList arr)
    {
        count=0;
        int num;
        System.out.print("Enter integer values to fill the arrayList -vevalue to stop: ");
        do
        {
            num = kb.nextInt();
            if (num >=0)
            {
                arr.add(count);
                count++;
            }
        } while (num > 0);

    }
```

So basically when you input 1 in the console, itll prompt you to add integers to the empty arraylist I established in the beginning. Im just having trouble with the first part alone with the syntax on how to get the user input to be added to the array list.

Comment: `arr.add(count);` seems to be the problem here.  You are just adding the 'count' variable to your array list, while the desire is to add the number you took from the user, `num = kb.nextInt();` to your array list.

Comment: This answer.
[ArrayList of int array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477628/arraylist-of-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using the raw type of ArrayList. The safer method is using a generic type, where you can't just add everything:

`ArrayList<Integer> numArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

2. To add the user input to the array, you have to add `num` since this is the integer you saved the user input in:

just replace
`arr.add(count);`
with
`arr.add(num);`