# How to convert int[] to Integer[]?

Tags: java, android, int, type-conversion, primitive-types

I need to pass a primitive `int` array (`int[]`) via intent extras, and use them in an extended `BaseAdapter` class, so I need to convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`

How can I do this?

Comment: Array adapter does this for you. 

Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java?rq=1

Comment: The best solution is to change your code so it doesn't need to do this in the first place. an Integer[] can use 7x more memory than an int[].

Comment: right now, there is so little members of arrays. So memory is not a big problem. And does BaseAdapter (for a Gallery) work with primitive arrays ?

Comment: [Trove4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.trove4j/trove4j/3.0.3) also has wrappers for primitives. Too bad, there are not so many examples on the net.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid theres no better solution than this

```
int[] a1 = ...
Integer[] a2 = new Integer[a1.length];
for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
   a2[i] = a1[i];
```

Comment: +1 other than changing your code to not use Integer[] anywhere ;)

Comment: I'm afraid you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

From @Eddie's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java?rq=1), you might want to look at this if you have access to the Apache lang library:

```
   Integer[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(oldArray);
```

Comment: Just FYI, I didn't down vote anybody.

Comment: I'm not gonna crib for being downvoted. How I wish I could meet my mysterious downvoter. :) . That aside, does this work for you?@mobilGelistirici

Comment: I don't know. haven't tried. will try now for you :D hmm, how do I import ArrayUtils ?

Comment: I think import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils should do it.