# Casting From int(primitive type) array to Integer(object type) array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I have an `int` array:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

How can I convert this array into an `Integer` array such as this:

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
int[] oldArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
Integer[] newArray = new Integer[oldArray.length];
int i = 0;
for (int value : oldArray) {
    newArray[i++] = Integer.valueOf(value);
}
```

Comment: In this case, it's probably easier to *not* use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] old = {1,2,3,4,5};

Integer[] arr = new Integer[old.length];
System.arraycopy(old, 0, arr, 0, old.length);
```

Or you can use [`Apache commons-lang`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

```
Integer[] arr = ArrayUtils.toObject(old);
```

Comment: In which package ArrayUtils class belongs?

Comment: You need the apache common-langs jar get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0)