# What's the simplest way to convert a String Array to an int Array using Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I'm currently learning how to use Java and my friend told me that this block of code can be simplified when using Java 8. He pointed out that the `parseIntArray` could be simplified. How would you do this in Java 8?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] tokens = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] ints = parseIntArray(tokens);
    }

    static int[] parseIntArray(String[] arr) {
        int[] ints = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
        return ints;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String Array to an Int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677530/converting-a-string-array-to-an-int-array)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For example:

```
static int[] parseIntArray(String[] arr) {
    return Stream.of(arr).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

So take a `Stream` of the `String[]`. Use `mapToInt` to call `Integer.parseInt` for each element and convert to an `int`. Then simply call `toArray` on the resultant `IntStream` to return the array.

Comment: Wow! Is this java? Certainly this is tidier than my solution. Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: @IrvinDenzelTorcuato Java 8, yes.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal it's Java 8 syntax, read about it in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: How do you get it as Integer[] array instead of int[] array?

Comment: What have you tried @Ridhuvarshan? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I have tried the same thing. It works and I am getting an int[] array. I need an integer array. I can get it by passing the int[] array using this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043087/5779242, 

but is it possible in one step?

Comment: How would you get an `Integer[]` from any other `Stream`? Can you use the code you linked to do it without copying? Why does my code generate an `int[]` but the linked code generate an `Integer[]`? @Ridhuvarshan

Comment: The linked answer is used to convert an `int[]` array to `Integer[]`. Your code is to convert `String[]` to `int[]`. I want `String[]` to `Integer[]` in one step.

Comment: @Ridhuvarshan indeed. Can you combine the two to do that? What does the linked answer do with the `IntStream`? Does my answer feature an `IntStresm`? How could you combine these two stream processing fragments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184450/discussion-between-ridhuvarshan-and-boris-the-spider).

Answer (score 19):

You may skip creating the token `String[]` array:

```
Pattern.compile(" ")
       .splitAsStream(input.nextLine()).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

The result of `Pattern.compile(" ")` may be remembered and reused, of course.

Comment: Wow, nifty. Didn't know `splitAsStream`.

Answer (score 2):

You could, also, obtain the array directly from a split:

```
String input; //Obtained somewhere
...
int[] result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray();
```

Here, `Arrays` has some nice methods to obtain the stream from an array, so you can split it directly in the call. After that, call `mapToInt` with `Integer::valueOf` to obtain the `IntStream` and `toArray` for your desired int array.