# Generics: Why Class<Integer[]> clazzIntArray = int[].class; does not work

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Following lines:

```
Class<Integer> clazzInteger = Integer.class;
Class<Integer> clazzInt = int.class;
```

Are valid and will compile/run even when:

```
if(clazzInt.equals(clazzInteger)) {
  System.out.println("clazzInt equals clazzInteger");
}else {
  System.out.println("clazzInt and clazzInteger are not equal");
}
```

Will print `clazzInt and clazzInteger are not equal`. But `Class<int> clazzInt = int.class;` do not work of course.

So why this analogy cannot be applied to array types?

```
Class<int[]> clazzIntArray = int[].class;
Class<Integer[]> clazzIntArray = int[].class;  // type mismatch: 
//cannot convert from Class<int[]> to Class<Integer[]>
```

But

```
Class<int[]> clazzIntArray = int[].class; // this is ok
```

I'm now baffled why `Class<Integer[]> clazzIntArray = int[].class` is invalid? What `Class<int[]>` means? And why the analogy between array and non array types does not work?

Comment: int[] and Integer[] are different classes. Instance of `int[]` is not an instance of `Integer[]`, and you cannot even cast between them iirc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java

Comment: @MarounMaroun You commented an answer :P

Comment: I'm astonished that `Class<Integer> clazzInt = int.class;` compiles.

Comment: @EJP why shouldn't it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why should it? They're different classes, and one isn't a subtype of the other. It doesn't appear to be a candidate for autoboxing either, although no doubt the explanation lies somewhere around there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoboxing has nothing to do with it. The Java Language Specification specifies (in [JLS 15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)) exactly what type `T.class` has:

- If `T` is a reference type, `T.class` has type `Class<T>`
- If `T` is a primitive type, `T.class` has type `Class<wrapper class of T>`

That's it. `int.class` has type `Class<Integer>` because the specification says so. `int[].class` has type `Class<int[]>` because the specification says so. `Class<int[]>` and `Class<Integer[]>` are not compatible types in Java.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but  `int.class` and 'Integer.class' are not equal. Does it means that `int.class` is somewhat subclass of `Integer.class` ?

Comment: @plastique: I didn't say `int.class` and `Integer.class` were equal (they are not). I said the expression `int.class` has type `Class<Integer>` (so does the expression `Integer.class`).

Comment: Ok, thank for clarification. Still, there has to be some relationship between `int.class` and `Integer.class`. Both has type `Class<Integer>` but their types are not equal. So sorry but i have to ask again is 'int.class' extending 'Integer.class' ?

Comment: @plastique: Sorry but your question doesn't make any sense. How can one value "extend" another one?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, [Autoboxing/Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) happens on individual elements inside the array. not with whole array type.

Java cannot magically convert whole primitive array to a Wrapper array. An individual element and an Array which consists of individual elements is the point here.

For ex : Array is a Basket and Fruit's inside the basket are elements (int's/Integer's)

Comment: Does it mean that Autoboxing is applied also on generics type parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing only works on single "instances" - an `int` can be autoboxed to an `Integer` and an `Integer` can be outboxed to an `int`. This is not true for arrays though. E.g., the statement `int[] arr = new Integer[10];` will not compile. The same holds for manipulating these classes via reflection.