# Casting primitive data type array to an OO array

Tags: java, casting, java-7, primitive-types

Is there an elegant, clean way for converting primitive data type `double` array to OO `Double` array (e.g. `double[]` into `Double[]`)?

There are some nice solutions out there, e.g.

```
int[] intArray = { ... };
Integer[] what = Arrays.stream( intArray ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
Integer[] ever = IntStream.of( intArray ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043087/1864294)), but this requires **Java 8**. Is there a similar elegant, performant way for **Java 7** and below?

Comment: I did some search online couple weeks ago about this  and people asked similar questions on SO also, seems like the only way is going through a loop.

Comment: can anyone comment on the efficiency when using `stream` with java 8?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)

Comment: @RPresle I clearly differentiate to this post; the post has solutions for Java 8, but no non-loop solution for < Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a one liner that compiles with Java 7, you can use [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) from Apache Commons. E.g.

```
Integer[] what = ArrayUtils.toObject(intArray);
```

Works for any primitive type. That's probably more "elegant" and "clean" than the Java 8 code you posted. If you want to avoid libraries like Apache Commons, I am afraid you have to use a for loop.