# How does in Java, AbstractList's get and size method gets called automatically when used in Anonymus class

Tags: java

while i was looking for something else i came across the below post in stackoverflow - [How to convert int[] to Integer[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)

here there is a code snippet as mentioned below,

```
int[] mInt = new int[10];
Integer[] mInteger = new Integer[mInt.length];

List<Integer> wrapper = new AbstractList<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mInt.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int i) {
        return mInt[i];
    }
};

wrapper.toArray(mInteger);
```

Can someone please explain the above code for me? 
am i missing something very fundamental in java language?

when i run through debugger, i see that get and size method gets called automatically, i.e without them being called explicitly from anywhere within or outside of the class !!
how so?!

Comment: Its because if the implementation of toArray funtion I believe where java calls upon the size and get function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an anonymous inner class that extends `AbstractList` and inherits all the methods from that class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

It just overrides the `size()` and the `get()` method and everything else you can find in the class hierarchy.

So it is a good idea to look at the source code of `AbstractList`.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java

As you can see, this class does not imlement a `toArray()` method. So you have to look at the next class in the hierarchy:

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java

And this class has an implementation of `toArray()` and inside this method the `size()` method is called.

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
        int size = size();
```

But there is no `get()` call in the method. So you have to dig a little deeper. Receiving elements in the method is done through an iterator. `AbstractCollection` does not implement the method `iterator()` to receive one. This is an abstract method. It is implemented in the `AbstractList` class.

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
...
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    try {
        int i = cursor;
        E next = get(i);
        lastRet = i;
        cursor = i + 1;
        return next;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        checkForComodification();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

This is the place where `get(i)` is called.

When I debug the code and set breakpoints in my IDE, I get the following stacktraces:

```
size:14, CopyToArray$1
toArray:180, AbstractCollection (java.util)
main:23, CopyToArray
```

and

```
size:14, CopyToArray$1
hasNext:364, AbstractList$Itr (java.util)
toArray:187, AbstractCollection (java.util)
main:23, CopyToArray
```

Where `CopyToArray` is my class with main method to call from the IDE. As you can see there is a class with the name `CopyToArray$1` which is the anonymous class that extends `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here you deal with something called anonymous class: 
You create a class "on-the-fly" that extends from AbstractList and override two methods : size and get

> when i run through debugger, i see that get and size method gets called automatically, i.e without them being called explicitly from anywhere within or outside of the class !! how so?!

I don't really know what do you mean by "automatically" by its possible that IDE calls these methods to show the content and size of that list in a debugger "variables" window or something. For example if you run them (not debugging) and place some `System.out.println` inside the overriden methods you won't see any prints on console unless you really call this array.

Now as for the referred question. This approach is not really a good idea to convert things, the answer with streams or with loops are much better.