# How to write a generic function which accepts arrays of literals

Tags: java, generics

I am unable to provide values of type `int[]`, `float[]`, etc. to a generic function. I get errors that say basically that `float[]` is the wrong type and `Float[]` is what the function actually takes.

Here's an example of a method I wrote, and I'm trying to give it values like `new int[]{0,1}` (created in library somewhere else).

```java
private static <T> JSONArray encodeArray(T[] array) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    Collections.addAll(arr, array);
    return arr;
}
```

Is it even possible to write my function signature to accept these arrays of literals?

I could go to the call site, and do a conversion of `float[]` to `Float[]`, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Conversion from `float[]` to `Float[]` seems pretty straightforward to me using a simple for loop.

Comment: @jrook It's not straightforward to me. I am just learning Java and the instance of `new Float[]` has no `.add()` or `.push()` methods.

Comment: I believe something like `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {y[i] = x[i];}` should work (`x:float[]` and `y:Float[]`. The function then can accept `y`.

Comment: This could solve your problem [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)

Comment: A very interesting read wrt. primitive generics: https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/erasure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to write my function signature to accept these
> arrays of literals?

It is possible, but the parameter type will have to be `Object`, because that is the only common superclass of "arrays of primitives" and "arrays of references" (e.g. it can't be `Object[]` since arrays of primitives are not subclasses of `Object[]`). (There are also some interfaces that all arrays implement, but I will ignore those for now.) Unfortunately, this means that you will lose type safety as the compiler will not be able to give an error at compile time if someone passes a non-array type in.

To do array operations on this `Object` value, you will need to use the methods in the reflection helper class `java.lang.reflect.Array`. So you can do something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

// ...

private static JSONArray encodeArray(Object array) {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0, n = Array.getLength(array); i < n; i++) {
        arr.add(Array.get(array, i)); // primitives are automatically wrapped
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method which accepts a generic array.

```
public <T> void printArray(T[] array){
        for (T element: array){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
```

You can't use primitives in generic functions. When generic are compiled, you end up with Object[] in the above example as the implementing type. As int[] and byte[] etc, do not extend Object[] you cannot use them interchangeably even if the code involved would be identical (again generics are not templates)

Comment: That's not what I asked for and neither will this compile.

Comment: It compiles perfectly.

Comment: The return type says `void` but you are returning `T[]`.

Comment: OK, my fault. Edited. But the answer to your question remains the same - you can't pass primitives to generic functions.

Comment: You did answer my question after I posted the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add on the solution from @Max-Reshetnyk, It is better if you check `ArrayList` for methods that help you `add` or `remove`... elements. Since primitive types are not meant to be used with generics, you should `AutoBox` them with their respective types and then use generics.

For instance:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] x = new Integer[1];
    x[0] = 1;
    printArray(x); 
  }

  public static <T>  void printArray(T[] array){
        for (T element: array){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```