# Converting Array of Primitives to Array of Containers in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there an elegant way to turn an array of primitives into an array of the corresponding container objects -- turn a `byte[]` into a `Byte[]`, for example?  Or am I stuck with looping through it and doing it manually?

Yeah, the `for` loop isn't exactly difficult.  Just kinda ugly.

Comment: And the other way around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**Apache Commons**

[Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) has a class [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) that defines these methods.

- All methods called `toObject(...)`
  convert from primitive array to wrapper array
- All called `toPrimitive(...)` convert
  from wrapper object array to
  primitive array

Example:

```
final int[]     original        = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
final Integer[] wrappers        = ArrayUtils.toObject(original);
final int[]     primitivesAgain = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(wrappers);
assert Arrays.equals(original, primitivesAgain);
```

---

**Guava**

But then I'd say that Arrays of wrapped primitives are not very useful, so you might want to have a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) instead, which provides Lists of all numeric types, backed by primitive arrays:

```
List<Integer> intList = Ints.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Long> longList   = Longs.asList(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L);
// etc.
```

The nice think about these array-backed collections is that

1. they are live views (i.e. updates to the array change the list and vice-versa)
2. the wrapper objects are only created when needed (e.g. when iterating the List)

See: [Guava Explained / Primitives](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained)

---

**Java 8**

On the other hand, with Java 8 lambdas / streams, you can make these conversions pretty simple without using external libraries:

```
int[] primitiveInts = {1, 2, 3};
Integer[] wrappedInts = Arrays.stream(primitiveInts)
                              .boxed()
                              .toArray(Integer[]::new);
int[] unwrappedInts = Arrays.stream(wrappedInts)
                             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                             .toArray();
assertArrayEquals(primitiveInts, unwrappedInts);

double[] primitiveDoubles = {1.1d, 2.2d, 3.3d};
Double[] wrappedDoubles = Arrays.stream(primitiveDoubles)
                                .boxed()
                                .toArray(Double[]::new);
double[] unwrappedDoubles = Arrays.stream(wrappedDoubles)
                                  .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                  .toArray();

assertArrayEquals(primitiveDoubles, unwrappedDoubles, 0.0001d);
```

Note that the Java 8 version works for `int`, `long` and `double`, but not for `byte`, as Arrays.stream() only has overloads for `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]` or a generic object `T[]`.

Comment: Is there an overload for `Arrays.stream(Byte [])` ?

Comment: Java 8 solution does not work for the question posted. `Arrays.stream()` doesn't have an overload for `byte[]`

Comment: @Peri461 true. I've only added the Java 8 stuff as an afterthought this year, the rest of the answer is several years older than Java 8

Comment: I see that now, apologies for down voting. Will fix when SO allows me.

Comment: @Peri461 no probs. down votes are a legit part of the game, no need to apologize.

Comment: This explains, why I don´t get my conversion to byte[] to work with a Java 8 stream. :-(

Answer (score 8):

You have to loop through your array.

---

Updated after @seanizer answer :

Basically the `toObject(byte[] array)` method will do the looping for you :

```
public static Byte[] toObject(byte[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (array.length == 0) {
        return EMPTY_BYTE_OBJECT_ARRAY;
    }
    final Byte[] result = new Byte[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result[i] = new Byte(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And unless you will really use the commons lang lib, you should simply reuse this method and avoid a useless dependency (IMHO).

Comment: I don't think the dependency is useless. The StringUtils.* methods are a huge time-saver. ArrayUtils is a bonus :-)

Comment: @seanizer I totally agree, Commons lang is really useful, I just say that having a dependency to it for only one static method isn't.

Comment: We should just delete this answer at this point.  @seanizer got it right.

Comment: @Erick I strongly disagree. Different viewpoints on a question are important

Comment: It's cheaper to include StringUtils.* than to write code.  What's another jar?  Our projects have a ton already.

Comment: Well maybe soon it will be guava instead of commons / lang, but we're not there yet :-)

Comment: Use Byte.valueOf instead of new Byte, less objects will be created.

Comment: I wanted a short operation for an undergrad Java project (without including outside dependencies of course). Here I keep my sanity knowing that there's not a Java library function that'll do it for me. The validity here is that we don't always get the luxury of calling external libraries.

Comment: You don't *have* to loop through the array. There are several alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

Just to suggest an alternative, with [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can use one of the primitive type utilities such as `Bytes` or `Ints` to create a `List` of the wrapper type:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
List<Byte> byteList = Bytes.asList(bytes);
```

Rather than looping through and converting each `byte`, these methods actually create a list that is backed by the given array. If you really need a `Byte[]`, this obviously doesn't directly give you what you need (though you can get it using `.toArray(new Byte[bytes.length])` of course). Collections are vastly superior to arrays for objects, though, and should be preferred when possible.

Comment: I agree. Collections rule, arrays suck, guava rules (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short generic way of doing it without using any external libraries and it works for all primitives:

```
import static java.lang.reflect.Array.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DeepConverter {

  public static void main(String args[]) {        
    long L1[][][] = {{{1,2},{3,4}}, {{5,6}}, {{7}},{{8,9,10,11}}};
    L1 = new long[2][0][7];
    Long L2[][] = (Long[][])box(L1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(L2));        
  }

  public static Object box(Object src) {        
    try {
        int length = src.getClass().isArray() ? getLength(src) : 0;        
        if(length == 0)
            return src;        
        Object dest = newInstance(typeCastTo(wrap(get(src, 0))), length);        
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            set(dest, i, wrap(get(src, i)));        
        return dest;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Object to wrap must be an array of primitives with no 0 dimensions");
    }
  }

  private static Class<?> typeCastTo(Object obj) {
    Class<?> type = obj.getClass();
    if(type.equals(boolean.class)) return Boolean.class;
    if(type.equals(byte.class)) return Byte.class;
    if(type.equals(char.class)) return Character.class;
    if(type.equals(double.class)) return Double.class;
    if(type.equals(float.class)) return Float.class;
    if(type.equals(int.class)) return Integer.class;
    if(type.equals(long.class)) return Long.class;
    if(type.equals(short.class)) return Short.class;
    if(type.equals(void.class)) return Void.class;        
    return type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an elegant way to turn an array of primitives into an array
>   of the corresponding container objects?

Suppose you have an array of bytes:

```
byte[] b = new byte[20];
... (fill b) ...
```

Then you can use [`Arrays.setAll(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to convert it:

```
Byte[] w = new Byte[b.length];
Arrays.setAll(w, i -> b[i]);
```

[`Arrays.parallelSetAll(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) is even faster:

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(w, i -> b[i]);
```

To verify the result:

```
System.out.println(b.getClass().getCanonicalName());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
System.out.println(w.getClass().getCanonicalName());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w));
```

If you need a universal wrapper for all kinds of primitive arrays, here it is:

```
public static Object[] wrap(Object a) {
    if (a == null)
        return null;
    int length = Array.getLength(a);
    Object b = length > 0 ? a : Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), 1);
    Object[] result = (Object[])Array.newInstance(Array.get(b, 0).getClass(), length);
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(result, i -> Array.get(a, i));
    return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Byte[] w = (Byte[])wrap(b);
```

Comment: There is also an extended version that correctly handles multidimensional arrays:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62212122/9772691

Answer (score 1):

After adding [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java/3770308#3770308), here's an awful answer, just for the heck of it. What bothers me about the Apache Commons ArrayUtils class is that there are 8 versions of the same method, just for different input types. I found a generic way to convert any primitive array into its wrapper equivalent (hence reducing the 8 different versions to one). This is the code:

```
public final class ArraysUtils {

    private ArraysUtils() {    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Object[] toWrapperArray(final Object primitiveArray) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(primitiveArray, "Null values are not supported");
        final Class<?> cls = primitiveArray.getClass();
        if (!cls.isArray() || !cls.getComponentType().isPrimitive()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Only primitive arrays are supported");
        }
        final int length = Array.getLength(primitiveArray);
        if (length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Only non-empty primitive arrays are supported");
        }
        final Object first = Array.get(primitiveArray, 0);
        Object[] arr = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(first.getClass(), length);
        arr[0] = first;
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Array.get(primitiveArray, i);
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

As you can see, there's quite a lot wrong with that method:

- There's no compile-time safety, the method parameter can be anything and only the method itself will validate runtime parameters, rigorously rejecting null values, empty arrays, non-arrays and non-primitive arrays
- Reflection was needed
- There is no way to support empty arrays without keeping some sort of lookup table between primitive and wrapper classes.

Anyway, here is a test suite for all the necessary scenarios, using JUnit's `Parameterized` runner:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ArraysUtilsTest {
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static List<Object> parameters() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                success(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}),
                success(new long[]{1L, 2L, 3L}, new Long[]{1L, 2L, 3L}),
                success(new byte[]{1, 2, 3}, new Byte[]{1, 2, 3}),
                success(new short[]{1, 2, 3}, new Short[]{1, 2, 3}),
                success(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'}, new Character[]{'a', 'b', 'c'}),
                success(new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, new Double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}),
                success(new float[]{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}, new Float[]{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}),
                success(new boolean[]{true, false, true}, new Boolean[]{true, false, true}),
                failure(null, NullPointerException.class, "Null"),
                failure("foo", IllegalArgumentException.class, "Non-array"),
                failure(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}, IllegalArgumentException.class, "Non-primitive array"),
                failure(new int[0], IllegalArgumentException.class, "Empty array")


            );
    }

    private static Object[] success(Object primitiveArray, Object[] wrapperArray) {
        return new Object[]{
                primitiveArray.getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                primitiveArray, null, wrapperArray};
    }

    private static Object[] failure(Object input,
                                    Class<? extends RuntimeException> exceptionClass,
                                    String description) {
        return new Object[]{description, input, exceptionClass, null};
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    // only used to generate the test name
    public String scenarioName;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public Object inputArray;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(2)
    public Class<? extends RuntimeException> expectedException;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(3)
    public Object[] expectedOutput;


    @Test
    public void runScenario() {
        try {
            Object[] wrapped = ArraysUtils.toWrapperArray(inputArray);
            if (expectedException != null) {
                fail(String.format("Expected %s to be thrown",
                                   expectedException.getSimpleName()));
            }
            assertThat(wrapped, is(equalTo(expectedOutput)));
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (expectedException == null) {
                fail(String.format("Expected no exception but got %swith message '%s'",
                                   e.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                   e.getMessage()));
            }
            if(!expectedException.isInstance(e)){
                fail(String.format("Expected %s but got %s with message '%s'",
                                   expectedException.getSimpleName(),
                                   e.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                   e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `char[]` to a `Character[]` array, we're first going to build a representative test ASCII char array from an `IntStream`, by using an accordingly size-allocated `CharBuffer`, inside a custom `Collector` (built from Supplier, Accumulator, Combiner and finisher Function):

```
Collector<Character, CharBuffer, char[]> charArrayCollector = Collector.of(
  () -> CharBuffer.allocate(95), 
  CharBuffer::put, 
  CharBuffer::put, 
  CharBuffer::array
);
```

Then, we can create an array from the standard printable ASCII range. Using `.range()` instead of `.iterate()` saves the need of limiting the resulting stream afterwards.

The iterated int values are cast to `char` each and mapped to a 'boxed' `Character` object stream, which is then collected into the test `char[]` array:

```
char[] asciiChars = IntStream.range(32, 127)
  .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
  .collect(charArrayCollector);
```

Now, we can convert the ASCII `char[]` array, again using an `IntStream`. This surrogates a classic `for` loop, by iterating over the array's indices, mapping each contained `char` into stream of 'boxed' `Character` objects, finally creating the desired `Character[]` array in the terminal operation. `Stream.iterate` is just for demonstration of an alternative way:

```
Character[] characters = IntStream.range(0, asciiChars.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf(chars[i]))
  .toArray(Character[]::new);

Character[] characters2 = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i += 1)
  .map(i -> asciiChars[i])
  .limit(asciiChars.length)
  .toArray(Character[]::new);
```

**Edit:**
Other primitive type arrays can be converted similarly; here, the boxing occurs in the `.mapToObj()` intermediate operation, where the source array elements are extracted and mapped to their object counterparts:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { Byte.MIN_VALUE, -1 , 0, 1, Byte.MAX_VALUE };
Byte[] boxedBytes = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> bytes[i])
  .toArray(Byte[]::new);

short[] shorts = new short[] { Short.MIN_VALUE, -1, 0, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE };
Short[] boxedShorts = IntStream.range(0, shorts.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> shorts[i])
  .toArray(Short[]::new);

float[] floats = new float[] { Float.MIN_VALUE, -1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, Float.MAX_VALUE };
Float[] boxedFLoats = IntStream.range(0, floats.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> floats[i])
  .toArray(Float[]::new);
```

For primitive values supported by the `Stream` API, the corresponding dedicated stream implementations and `.boxed()`can be used instead:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1, 0, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE };
Integer[] integers = IntStream.of(ints)
  .boxed()
  .toArray(Integer[]::new);

long[] longs = new long[] { Long.MIN_VALUE, -1l, 0l, 1l, Long.MAX_VALUE };
Long[] boxedLongs = LongStream.of(longs)
  .boxed()
  .toArray(Long[]::new);

double[] doubles = new double[] { Double.MIN_VALUE, -1.0, 0, 1.0, Double.MAX_VALUE };
Double[] boxedDoubles = DoubleStream.of(doubles)
  .boxed()
  .toArray(Double[]::new);
```