# Array parameter behavior on java

Tags: java, arrays

I just notice a weird behavior, look at the example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    aaa(1,2);
  }

  public static void aaa(int... a){
    bbb(a);
    ccc(a);
  }

  public static void bbb(int... a){

  }

  public static void ccc(Object... a){

  }
```

On `bbb` `a` is an array {1,2} (`a = {1,2}`)

On `ccc` `a` is an array of array's  which the first array value is {1,2} (`a = { {1,2} }`)

There are places on my code that I must define it as `Object`. But of course the second behavior is not desired.. I want the same behavior for both definitions (both `Object...` and `int...` will contain `{1,2}`). How do I do it?

The preferred value is an array of values and not and array of arrays. For example `bbb` parameter is ok, and the desired parameter in `ccc` is `{1,2}` from type `Object`.

If will try to do something like this is order to get the inner array I will fail:

```
  public static void ccc(Object... a){
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(a.getClass().isArray()){
      for(Object in_obj: (Object[])obj){
        list.add(in_obj);
      }
    }

    // rest of the code..
  }
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: I cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]` because the array is primitive.. Is there a solution for that? I dont use only with int, but with a lot of primitive(and not primitive)..

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: Object... a makes an array of objects and you put a single object (an array which is made of {1,2}) into that. So you have {{1,2},another object}

Comment: is you question about why you can put int in a method which requires object??

Comment: Java doesn't autobox arrays of primitives into arrays of wrapper types. You'll have to do this transformation by yourself if you want that.

Comment: How do you recommend to do it? if I send one value it doesnt convert it to array of arrays..

Comment: create an Object array of the same length as the int array, loop through the int array, change each int to an Integer and add the Integer to the Object array. Then call ccc with the Object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your input, I want also credit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606338/cast-primitive-type-array-into-object-array-in-java) thread. What I've build is this:

```
  private Object[] toArrayObject(Object[] array){   
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object obj: array){
      if(obj.getClass().isArray()){
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(getArray(obj)));
      } else{
        list.add(obj);
      }
    }

    return list.toArray();
  }

  private Object[] getArray(Object val){
    Class<?>[] ARRAY_PRIMITIVE_TYPES = { 
        int[].class, float[].class, double[].class, boolean[].class, 
        byte[].class, short[].class, long[].class, char[].class 
    };

    Class<?> valKlass = val.getClass();
    Object[] outputArray = null;

    for(Class<?> arrKlass : ARRAY_PRIMITIVE_TYPES){
      if(valKlass.isAssignableFrom(arrKlass)){
        int arrlength = Array.getLength(val);
        outputArray = new Object[arrlength];
        for(int i = 0; i < arrlength; ++i){
          outputArray[i] = Array.get(val, i);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if(outputArray == null) // not primitive type array
        outputArray = (Object[])val;

    return outputArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer instead of int.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    aaa(1,2);
  }

  public static void aaa(Integer... a){
    bbb(a);
    ccc(a);
  }

  public static void bbb(Integer... a){

  }

  public static void ccc(Object... a){

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java will not autobox an `int` array into an `Integer` array. One thing you could do is, in `ccc`, go through each `Object` in `a` and check if it is an `int[]`, and if so, process those `int`s separately.

Another thing you could do is box the `int` array first; either write your own method to do it, or e.g. Apache Commons Lang provides [ArrayUtils.toObject()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29).

You could also just use `Integer` all around to begin with.

Still, if you find yourself in this situation, you should take a step back and think about whether or not what you're doing makes the most sense.