# Create a class in java that can receive different types

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I want to implement this class to receive different types of arrays, like String, int, double,  etc:

```
public class BubbleSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private T [] A;
public BubbleSort(T [] A) {
    this.A = A;
}

public void bubbleSort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.A.length - 1; j--) {
            if (this.A[j].compareTo(this.A[j - 1]) < 0) {
                T aux = this.A[j];
                this.A[j] = this.A[j - 1];
                this.A[j - 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm creating an object of that class like this:

```
double A[] = { 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3 };    
BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort(A);
```

I get an error that tell me the constructor of BubbleSort(double[]) is not defined. I think I'm doing something wrong with the generic type class and i need some help.

Cumps.

Comment: Also, generics don't work with primitive types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the posto you have mentioned don't answer my question

Comment: Why do you think so? Do you know what a raw type is now? Do you see how it applies to your situation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So it's impossible what i'm trying to do?

Comment: @AnubianNoob thank you for your help, stack overflow needs more people like you :)

Comment: You can use a `Double[]`.

Comment: @arturataide That was a joke, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parameterize `BubbleSort` *and* use an array of a reference type, not a primitive type (since generics only works with reference types):

```
Double[] A = { 3d, 2d, 4d, 6d, 7d, 1d, 2d, 3d };    // notice Double ref. type
BubbleSort<Double> bs = new BubbleSort<Double>(A);  // notice <Double> type param.
```

Also notice that I've attached `[]` to the type of the array, which is `Double`. It is also valid to attach it to the variable name as you have done, but it is more conventional to attach it to the type.

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked as I expected. Thanks.

Comment: I also find it easier to read the data type with the `[]` attached to the type of the array. You can know instantly that this variable is an array of the given type. I have no idea why Java allows attaching the `[]` to the variable name. It's confusing to distinguish between `Double A` and `Double A[]`.

Comment: If you need to convert primitive arrays (in the event you're receiving a primitive array and you don't have the control to change the sender logic to send a reference type array), take a look at this question: [Cast primitive type array into object array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606338/cast-primitive-type-array-into-object-array-in-java)