# Make function generic for List<Boolean> and boolean[]

Tags: java, generics

I have two functions which check if all elements of an array or list are `true`. I'm having trouble combining the two. How can I make the functions into one generic Java function.

```
public static boolean allTrue(boolean[] booleans) {
    if (booleans == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (boolean bool : booleans) {
        if (!bool) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean allTrue(List<Boolean> booleans) {
    if (booleans == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (boolean bool : booleans) {
        if (!bool) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Guava by any chance?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5606435/2310289

Comment: @shmosel No Guava

Comment: How about Java 8?

Comment: @shmosel No Java 8 as well, only backported Java 8 lambda expressions with Retrolambda

Comment: I think @shmosel's answer is pretty good, you can take a look at the `Booleans` class and replicate the `asList` method.

Comment: Without a third-party library, what you have is as good as it gets.  (Though it's generally best policy to throw on `null` instead of trying to return an answer.)

Comment: And if you're treating `null` as an empty array, it should return `true` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Guava, you can wrap the boolean array in [`Booleans.asList()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#asList-boolean...-) and pass it as a list:

```
public static boolean allTrue(boolean[] booleans) {
    return booleans != null && allTrue(Booleans.asList(booleans));
}
```

Comment: Under the hood, this probably is not more efficient than the answer I gave.

Comment: I don't see any indication OP was concerned about efficiency.

Comment: Both answers are less efficient than the code posted in the question.

Comment: @Winter There is no requirement for efficiency improvement

Comment: Under the hood, it's returning a special wrapper around the boolean array: `BooleanArrayAsList`, no allocation and no copying of array elements.

Comment: @ScaryWombat There's no requirement for efficiency decrement either. It's not even generic, just a different overload so it's not getting any closer to what OP asks anyway.

Comment: @Winter I'm pretty sure OP didn't mean generic in the technical sense. He just wants to unify the logic.

Comment: @shmosel I'm pretty sure he mean "generic" (as stated in question) and need an explanation on why it's not possible to do it in only one generic function.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606435/2310289

You could just accept an Object

```
public static boolean allTrue(Object booleans) {
```

and then check for `instanceof boolean[]` or `instanceof List<Boolean>` and then perform different code within the method.

Again, not really an improvement, but a bit closer to code unification

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer given by @Joel was a good one, except for the issue pointed out in the comment.  If we just convert `boolean[]` to `Boolean[]`, we can try the following:

```
public static boolean allTrue(List<Boolean> booleans) {
    if (booleans == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (boolean bool : booleans) {
        if (!bool) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean allTrue(boolean[] booleans) {
    Boolean[] newArray = new Boolean[booleans.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (boolean value : booleans) {
        newArray[i++] = Boolean.valueOf(value);
    }

    return Arrays.asList(newArray);
}
```

Comment: How is that not an improvement? The logic of `allTrue` now only needs to be changed in one location if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The common ancestor for `List<Boolean>` and `boolean[]` is `Object`, so unless you are okay with `allTrue(Object booleans)`, you cannot do it with one method.

If you change your method signature to `allTrue(Iterable<Boolean> booleans)`, all you have to do is create a special `Iterator<Boolean>` to traverse the boolean array.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class BooleanAllTrue {
    public static boolean allTrue(Iterable<Boolean> booleans) {
        if (booleans == null) return false;

        for (Boolean bool : booleans) {
            if (!bool) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static Iterable<Boolean> asIterable(final boolean[] booleens) {
        return new Iterable<Boolean>() {
            public Iterator<Boolean> iterator() {
                final boolean[] booleans = booleens;
                return new Iterator<Boolean>() {
                    private int i = 0;

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return i < booleans.length;
                    }

                    public Boolean next() {
                        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        return booleans[i++];
                    }

                    public void remove() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");}
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(allTrue(asIterable(new boolean[]{true, true})));
        System.out.println(allTrue(asIterable(new boolean[]{true, false})));
        try {
            asIterable(new boolean[0]).iterator().next();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // expected
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the `allTrue(boolean[] booleans)` method.

```
public static boolean allTrue(boolean[] booleans) {
    return allTrue(asIterable(booleans));
}
```

Comment: *The common ancestor for `List<Boolean>` and `boolean[]` is `Object`*. If you're counting interfaces, they both implement `Serializable`. Not that that's relevant to your point.