# What is the best way of converting List<Long> object to long[] array in java?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any utility method to convert a list of Numerical types to array of primitive type?
In other words I am looking for a better solution than this.

```
private long[] toArray(List<Long> values) {
    long[] result = new long[values.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Long l : values)
        result[i++] = l;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java

Comment: as You want still your solution do not forget about `l.longValue();`

Comment: @Vash: `longValue()` isn't necessary since there's autoboxing

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since Java 8, you can do the following:

```
long[] result = values.stream().mapToLong(l -> l).toArray();
```

What's happening here?

1. We convert the `List<Long>` into a `Stream<Long>`.
2. We call [`mapToLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) on it to get a `LongStream`

   - The argument to `mapToLong` is a [`ToLongFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToLongFunction.html), which has a `long` as the result type.
   - Because Java automatically unboxes a `Long` to a `long`, writing `l -> l` as the lambda expression works. The `Long` is converted to a `long` there. We could also be more explicit and use `Long::longValue` instead.
3. We call [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#toArray--), which returns a `long[]`

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: @VaidAbhishek Done :).

Comment: I tried to return Long[] with your example but still when I call toArray it return long[]. can you please give a full method call for returning Long[]

Comment: @MoayadAbuJaber You want a `Long[]` instead? That's just `values.toArray(new Long[0])`

Comment: In Android this call requires min API level 24 so if you're targeting a lower level, you can't use this.

Answer (score 34):

**[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** : **[Longs.toArray(Collection)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html)**

```
long[] result = Longs.toArray(values);
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(Long[] array)` from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html).

```
Long[] l = values.toArray(new Long[values.size()]);
long[] l = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(l);
```

Comment: You might need to specify that you want a `long` array returned: `values.toArray(new long[0]);`

Comment: @Gary Buyn: You can't use primitive types as generic arguments.

Comment: I don't know why you get 4 up votes but this code would not even compile you cannot cast from Object[] to long[].

Comment: @Vash Yes, I realized it as soon as I posted it.

Comment: If using gradle (as in android) use  dependency `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'`(change to latest version) to add the Apache Commons library (and its class `ArrayUtils`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall about some native method that will do that but what is wrong with creating a self one ;-).

```
public class YasinUtilities {

    public static long[] toArray(Iterator<Long) values) { //Better choice would be Enumerator but easier is this way. 

      if(value == null) {
        //return null or throw exception 
      }

      long[] result = new long[values.size()];

      Long current = null;
      int i = 0;
      while(values.hasNext()) {

       current = values.next();

       if(current == null) {
         result[i++] = 0L; //or -1;
       } else {
         result[i++] = current.longValue();
       }
      }
   } 
}
```