# Converting a List to an Array in Java

Tags: java

I am a List of Long type and would like to convert it to an array of long type.

However when adding elements to the list, it says it is unable to find method "add(int)"

my code looks like below

```
package collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ListToArray {

    private static List<Long> list;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        list=new ArrayList<Long>();
        list.add(121145788);
        list.add(1245898);

        long[] arr=new long[list.size()];

        arr=list.toArray();

    }
}
```

Error I am getting are

**Error(16,13):  cannot find method add(int).
Error(21,25):  incompatible types**

Can someone point out where it's going wrong.

Comment: what java version are you using?

Comment: It shouldn't necessary, but trying postfixing the numbers with L to make them long literals: `121145788L`. I would expect that it could coerce it without your intervention though.

Comment: Why did you edit the code in the question? As it is now, it won't give you the error anymore. In its current state, the question should be closed because the problem can't be reproduced ....

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, you should add `L` to force the value to be a `long`:

```
list.add(121145788L);
list.add(1245898L);
```

Explanation:

the values you wanted to add are `int`s, and `list` is for `long`s. Adding the `L` makes the compiler use the number literal as a value of type **`L`**`ong` explicitly, and that can be added to the list.

Without it, the numbers are treated as `Integers`, and those can't be added to a list of type `Long`, hence

```
cannot find method add(int)
```

There is a method `add(long)`, and that's what is used when the `L` is used.

To convert to an array, you need to do it the old fashioned way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]=list.get(i);
}
```

This is because `long` is a [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and `Long` is a reference type (i.e. it is an `Object`). Casting from primitives to Objects isn't always easy. In this case, the old fashioned way works well.

Comment: that's wrong a bit. even `list.add(1);` will fail because there is nothing to do with large numbers, in this case, it is because of Java will try to auto box int into Integer and we expect Long there. That's why `L` helps. Literal treated as long will be boxed to Long

Comment: @john true, but how's that relevant? I'm talking about the large numbers to explain the difference between `int` and `long`. I'm not saying that it fails because the numbers are too small or something./

Comment: And that's correct, if you have something like 1234565756746546 you will get something like 'number is too large' and need to add L to explicitly say it is long literal. but that's not the case with the example provided in the question

Comment: @john I see. Thanks, I didn't know that. (regarding comment #2:) Yes, I just tested that and you're completely right. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, it is better now :)

Answer (score 2):

First, this is your code but with all the fixes!

```
    private static List<Long> list;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        list=new ArrayList<Long>();
        list.add(121145788L);
        list.add(1245898L);

        Long[] arr = new Long[list.size()];

        list.toArray(arr);

    }
```

And here is some explanation:

- you have a list of type `Long`. When you `add()` items to the list - compiler expects them to be of type `Long`, but you are adding literal values (plain numbers like 121145788) so those are treated as integers (type `int`) and are autoboxed to `Integer` instead of `Long`. So add `L` to treat literals as `long` and then they are autoboxed into `Long`. Fine for the compiler :)
- `list.toArray(arr);` this is the correct method to kinda convert a list to an array. Because the method you used returns array of `Object` and `arr` you created is not an array of `Object`.
- And again this correct method I used takes T[] as input, so you need to change your `arr` declaration a bit to make it of type `Long` instead of an array of primitive type `long`.

If for some reason you need `long[]`, the easiest way would be:

```
long[] arr = new long[list.size()];

for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: So there is no way I cant use an array of type long?

Comment: @redsoxlost I added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Error(16,13): cannot find method add(int), this is because you are passing int instead of a Long value in a list of Long. You should be doing:

```
list.add(121145788l);
```

And for the second error follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175004/what-is-the-best-way-of-converting-listlong-object-to-long-array-in-java).Hope,it helps!

Answer (score 0):

JVM doesn't automatically cast int (short, byte, char) to Long. It's explained on the next link.

[Java: Why can't I cast int to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765874/java-why-cant-i-cast-int-to-long)

Converting `List<Long>` to `long[]` is possible and also is answered on SO.

[How to convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960431/9046830)

That's the answers:

using Java 8 streams

```
    long[] arr = list.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).toArray();
```

using [Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#toArray(java.util.Collection))

```
    long[] arr = Longs.toArray(list);
```

using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

```
    long[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Long[0]))
```