# Error converting from ArrayList to double[]?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, list, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` called `out`, and I need to convert it to a `double[]`. The examples I've found online have said two things:

First, try:

```
double[] d = new double[out.size()];
out.toArray(d);
```

However, this produces the error (eclipse):

```
The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (double[]).
```

The second solution I found was on StackOverflow, and was:

```
double[] dx = Arrays.copyOf(out.toArray(), out.toArray().length, double[].class);
```

However, this produces the error:

```
The method copyOf(U[], int, Class<? extends T[]>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], int, Class<double[]>)
```

What is causing these errors, and how do I convert `out` to `double[]` without creating these problems? `out` indeed holds only double values.

Thanks!

Comment: how you define `out`? must it be double[] or Double[] is acceptable?

Comment: Uh... downvote, why? Research was made, multiple things were attempted, and I still had a question.

Comment: @Emrakul I did not vote up or down, but a SSCCE would make this question much better IMO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are trying to convert `ArrayList` containing `Double` objects to primitive `double[]`

```
public static double[] convertDoubles(List<Double> doubles)
{
    double[] ret = new double[doubles.size()];
    Iterator<Double> iterator = doubles.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        ret[i] = iterator.next();
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

ALternately, Apache Commons has a `ArrayUtils` class, which has a method `toPrimitive()`

```
 ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(out.toArray(new Double[out.size()]));
```

but i feel it is pretty easy to do this by yourself as shown above instead of using external libraries.

Comment: Also works with `for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) ret[i] = out.get(i).doubleValue();`, no need for an iterator. Thank you!

Comment: This won't work. i=i++ results in i always being 0, put simply i++; Also, explicit unboxing (.doubleValue()) is unnecessary.

Comment: incorporated the suggested changes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
Double[] d = new Double[out.size()];
out.toArray(d);
```

i.e use the class `Double` and not the primitive type `double`

The error messages seem to imply that this is the issue. After all, since `Double` is a wrapper class around the primitive type `double` it is essentially a different type, and compiler will treat it as such.

Comment: @Telthien in that case could you redefine the list as `List<double>`

Comment: @Telthien or you could use [ArrayUtils](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java) as shown in the link to convert from `Double[]` to `double[]`

Answer (score 1):

Generics does not work with primitive types that's why you are getting an error. Use `Double array` instead of `primitive double`. Try this -

```
Double[] d = new Double[out.size()];
out.toArray(d);
double[] d1 = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(d);
```

Comment: what is the package for ArrayUtils