# Wrapping a double[] to a Double[]

Tags: java

I am really new to java. I have come up to something I really can't get my head around. I understand that *Double* is a wrapper class and that you can wrap a double value inside an object of the said class. So a code looking something like this would work fine

```java
double pi = 3.14;
Double tempVariable = new Double(pi);
```

So it seemed perfectly logical to me that since I can wrap a *double* to a *Double*, it would be as easy to wrap a *double[]* to a *Double[]*. But this isn't the case. 
I tried everything I could think of (syntax alterations - creating an object of type Object containing the said *double[]* and then casting to Double[], dealing with the *Double* object as if it was an *array*) but none of these worked.

I am using j2me.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

@MightyPork : That was the first thing I tried to do. The code I think, tries to do this is the following:

```java
public Double[] modelWeights = new Double[9];
modelweights = {-1.31,1.39,-0.36,1.55,1.55,-2.03,2.25,2.27,-0.72};
```

But this won't work. I have no idea why.

@Abimaran Kugathasan:: I saw *ArrayUtils* yesterday and it would be a great solution but I am using j2me and classes such as *List* or *HashSet* (that are required for *ArrayUtils*) are not implemented in j2me. Am I missing something?

EDIT:: The thread linked by Abimaran Kugathasan had indeed other answers pretty close to fge's answer. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: yes, suggestion.. make array of Double and copy your doubles in there.

Comment: possibel duplicate of [Converting Array of Primitives to Array of Containers in Java][1] 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770289/converting-array-of-primitives-to-array-of-containers-in-java

Comment: Double[] doubles = ArrayUtils.toObject(d);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to one of Java's historical baggage, arrays.

What happens is that similarly to the fact that you have primitive types `double` and their "class equivalent" `Double`, and that you can use one seamlessly for the other is because (since Java 5) in this case the compiler does boxing/unboxing for you.

But it won't do so for arrays; so `Double[]` is not a "wrapper class" for `double[]`.

If you have a `double[]` array which you want to "turn into" a `Double[]`, you have no choice but to copy yourself... For instance:

```
final double[] primitiveArray = ...;

final int len = primitiveArray.length;

final Double[] boxedArray = new Double[len];

for (int index = 0; index < len; index++)
    boxedArray[index] = Double.valueOf(primitiveArray[index]);
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thank you very much. This was one of the things i tried yesterday but without Double.valueOf (). So i got the error "double cannot be converted to Double."

Thanks again