# how to find index of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i am trying to use this function but it is giving that index is -1.
so what can i do

```
int[] veer = {14,25,14,56,15,36,56,77,18,29,49};

int a = Arrays.asList(veer).indexOf(14);

System.out.println("my array at position 14 is :" + (a));
```

Comment: Your question is poorly structured, but from what I managed to understand why dont you just use `array[indexNumber]` to print the element at that index??

Comment: "at position 14" - `indexOf` returns the location _of_ the first occurrence of this value, not the element _at_ that index. If you are using arrays why do you not use the `[]` operator? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: it is unclear if you want the value at position 14, or if you want the position of value 14. In first case you should use veer[14], in second case, you should use a for loop to cycle through the array elements. In either case you don't need to convert the array to a list.

Comment: Please ask question carefully. What do you want to find index of number or index of array.

Answer (score 7):

I assume, you want to learn/test what `indexOf` is doing. The problem is, that `Arrays.asList(veer)` returns list containing one element - whole array.

When I split the code to multiple lines, it is doing:

```
    int[] orig = {14,25,14,56,15,36,56,77,18,29,49};
    List<int[]> origList = Arrays.asList(orig);
```

and that's why, your indexOf is not able to find 14 in a list, because simply said, there is no integer in list.

When you use wrapper type, it works as you might expect

```
    Integer[] veer = {14,25,14,56,15,36,56,77,18,29,49};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(veer);
    int a = list.indexOf(25); // I changed to 25
    System.out.println("my array at position 25 is :" + a);
```

which prints index 1.

To learn about wrapping/unwrapping array, you can read more here [Converting Array of Primitives to Array of Containers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3770289/384674) but changing `int[]` to `Integer[]` is simplest in this case (you are not forced by API to accept `int[]`).

Comment: I'd like downvoters to let me know what they do not agree with !

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
int[] veer = {14,25,14,56,15,36,56,77,18,29,49};
```

to

```
Integer[] veer = {14,25,14,56,15,36,56,77,18,29,49};
```

because `indexOf` expect a `object` type since it is primitive it is return as -1(-1 represents not found)