# Cast Long[] to long[]

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting an array of objects to an array of their primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types)

I making a `Parcel` for Android and I'm trying to package an `ArrayList<Long>` (toArray gives me `Long[]`) by converting it to `long[]`, is there a simple way to do this?

I realize I can loop through but I guess I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easier way than looping. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754294/convert-an-array-of-primitive-longs-into-a-list-of-longs) is about doing the opposite but the idea is the same...

Since another answer recommends Apache Commons and you are on Android - if I were to include an additional dependency I would rather go for [guava Longs utility class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
long[] primitive = Longs.toArray(listOfLongObjects);
```

For reference, the code is:

```
  public static long[] toArray(Collection<? extends Number> collection) {
    if (collection instanceof LongArrayAsList) {
      return ((LongArrayAsList) collection).toLongArray();
    }

    Object[] boxedArray = collection.toArray();
    int len = boxedArray.length;
    long[] array = new long[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      // checkNotNull for GWT (do not optimize)
      array[i] = ((Number) checkNotNull(boxedArray[i])).longValue();
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use Apache commons [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html):

```
long[] longArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(longObjectArray);
```

or in Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
long[] longArray = Longs.toArray(Arrays.asList(longObjectArray));
```

Comment: Nice, but I wouldn't include a whole new jar to my project just to avoid implementing one simple loop myself.

Comment: @Ridcully once you include it, you'll probably find yourself using it again and again. It's full of useful, *common* (hence the name) methods that reduces the amount of tedious boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I agree with Ridcully I try to keep the APK as small as possible.

Comment: You could always just copy that particular method in, making sure to keep a note where it's from (and even keeping the package the same org.apache...) It is Apache licensed after all. http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.java?view=markup#l2885 Then if (when) you DO decide to include the whole thing, easy switch :)

Comment: In that case I would rather recommend guava.

Comment: If APK size is your concern, you should be using Proguard anyway.

Comment: @PhilKeeling I agree -- would be nice if some commons libraries were part of Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

`Long` and `long` are different types. `Long` is a class. `long` is a primitive. Autoboxing introduced to java 5 can confuse some people because bi-directional transformation between `Long` and `long` is done automatically by compiler. However this is not correct for arrays. This means that you have to create new array of type `long` and copy element-by-element:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
// this way you create array of Long
Long[] arr1 = list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]);

// this way you create array of long
long[] arr2 = new long[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Long e : list) {
    arr2[i++] = e; // autoboxing does the job here
}
```

Obviously you can use `System.arrcopy()` instead of writing loop yourself. However id does not make any difference.