# Type mismatch: boolean[], Boolean[], ArrayList<Boolean>

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I am trying to construct a boolean[][] from a text file.  I am reading in each character, storing in an ArrayList (1s as true and 0s as false).  I tried ArrayList, but got compile errors, unexpected element.  So, I build an ArrayList, and try to store it in an ArrayList>.  My last problem is with the type difference between boolean and Boolean in the following method.  seedInProgress is the ArrayList> constructed by finishLine().  I am trying to copy it all out to a boolean[][] inside the for loop.

```
public void finishSeed(ArrayList<Boolean> lastLine) {
    finishLine(lastLine);
    seed = new boolean[seedInProgress.size()][seedInProgress.get(0).size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < seedInProgress.size(); i++ ) {
        seed[i] = seedInProgress.get(i).toArray()
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
SeedFactory.java:75: error: incompatible types
            seed[i] = seedInProgress.get(i).toArray();
                                                   ^
  required: boolean[]
  found:    Object[]
1 error
```

but I can't cast it to boolean[], and Boolean[] is still an Object[].

How can I get a boolean[] from an ArrayList, or alternatively, how can I make an ArrayList?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting an array of objects to an array of their primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types)

Comment: Simple quiestion: Is changing the type of seed from `boolean` to `Boolean` possible in your case or are you restricted?

Comment: @PaulBellora, that one didn't come up in my searches, but it is helpful info though this is a slightly different problem, at least from a newbie's perspective (maybe it isn't really).

Comment: @Gamb, that would be easier, but the entire rest of the app would need to be reworked

Comment: @nexus_2006 That's why I asked. Not an option then, the quickest way is to iterate then. No use in adding a library just to solve a particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a lowercase `boolean[]` from an `ArrayList<Boolean>`, you have to do the `for` loop yourself, or use a utility method that does the same thing, a la [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Booleans.toArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29).

The `for` loop is what you'd expect:

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Whether the original method is poorly designed or not, this solved the actual problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Java won't autobox whole arrays at a time, if that is what you were hoping. Ie

```
boolean b;
Boolean B;
a = B; // OK
boolean[] bs;
Boolean[] Bs;
bs = Bs; // compiler error
```

But really why are you creating a `List<Boolean>` first? I would simply pass the line as a String, because it *is* a String. And your method is a bit too complicated - it does too much and knows about too much.

See if this method helps:

```
public static boolean[] toBooleanArray(String line) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[line.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
        array[i] = line.charAt(I) == '1';
    return array;
}
```

Your file could be then converted to a `List<boolean[]>` like this:

```
List<boolean[]> lines = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
// loop reading "line" from file
    lines.add(toBooleanArray(line));
```

then to get a `boolean[][]`:

```
boolean[][] array = lines.toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've seen this one undergo several edits :)  I was hoping for some autoboxing action, but thanks for telling me why it doesn't work.  I am making a `List` because I want to use the methods like add() in the method that constructs the list from a text file.  While reading the file, it doesn't know how long the list will be, so the only other way I could figure out how to do it is to make an array of length 1, then each character read from the file create a new array of length oldArray+1, seemed wasteful but maybe not.