# Why do I get a syntax error

Tags: java

Why do I get an error at `.ToArray` .  (Syntax) Seems like im putting the right paramater value.

Thanks for your response.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Vector {


private double doubleComposantes[];
private int intNombreDeComposante = 0;


public Vector(String strComposantes) {

    strComposantes = strComposantes.trim();
    intNombreDeComposante = getNumberOfComposantes(strComposantes);
}

private int getNumberOfComposantes(final String strComposantes) {

    return strComposantes.split(",").length;
}


private double[] getAllComposantes(final String strComposantes) {

    final String[] strComposantesSplitted = strComposantes.split(",");
    LinkedList<Double> doubleComposantesConvertis = new LinkedList<Double>();

    for (String strComposante : strComposantesSplitted) {

        doubleComposantesConvertis.add(Double.valueOf(strComposante));

    }

    int intLongueur = doubleComposantesConvertis.size();
    return doubleComposantesConvertis.toArray(new double[intLongueur]); // error at toArray()
}

}
```

Comment: Change `double` to `Double`.

Answer (score 5):

`toArray` signature in LinkedList is

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

and since `T` will be erased to `Object` at runtime you can use only `Object` types here, not primitive types. Try with `Double` instead of `double`

```
return doubleComposantesConvertis.toArray(new Double[intLongueur]);
```

Notice you would also have to change return type of your method to `Double[]`

---

Update:

if you want to return `double[]` and can use external libraries then you can use [`Doubles.toArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray-java.util.Collection-) from [guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
return Doubles.toArray(doubleComposantesConvertis);//will return double[]
```

Comment: Ah yes! I dont think Double will work. Do you know another alternative or I should write my own method to copy every list elements in a array

Comment: @MalikDz unfortunately you will not be able to use build in methods to create `double[]`. You would have to copy its elements manually or use some external libraries. I suspect guava may have some classes that could be helpful here but I didn't used them yet.

Comment: @MalikDz check my updated answer if you are interested in guava solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
doubleComposantesConvertis.toArray(new Double[intLongueur]);
```

Notice that the `Double` is upper case.  That's because it's an object instead of a primitive.

Comment: Return type is double[] not Double[]

Comment: @m0skit0 the return type of the method you're in doesn't change the parameter types of the libraries you use.  This could happen with generics, but notice that the `T` of `toArray` has no connection to the `double[]` of his `getAllComposantes`.

Comment: I mean `return doubleComposantesConvertis.toArray(new Double[intLongueur])` will raise a compile error.

Comment: @m0skit0 yep.  The easiest solution is to change his method signature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types  Or, you can use the apache commons.

Answer (score 0):

toArray() receives an array of objects, you're passing an array of double, and it's a primitive not object. Autoboxing doesn't apply for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`double[]` is not `Double[]`. You either change your return value to `Double[]` or build manually a `double[]`.

I suggest you avoid using arrays in your code and use a `List` instead. This way you won't have this problem. Only use arrays when strictly necessary.

```
private List<Double> getAllComposantes(final String strComposantes) {
    final String[] strComposantesSplitted = strComposantes.split(",");
    final List<Double> doubleComposantesConvertis = new LinkedList<Double>();
    for (String strComposante : strComposantesSplitted) {
        doubleComposantesConvertis.add(Double.valueOf(strComposante));
    }
    return doubleComposantesConvertis;
}
```

Also make sure you need `LinkedList` for some reason instead of `ArrayList` (which [will perform better in most cases](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo)).

Answer (score 0):

The changes mentioned will fix your problem, but really you'd be better off using the 0-argument toArray method.