# Creating primitive array out of wrapper collection in java

Tags: java, collections

Is there a fast (in terms of saving programmers time not the execution time of program) utility method in default java libraries (without any external 3rd util libs)  which would enable to create primitive array from a primitive wrapper collection?

Example:

```
int[] array = magicMethod(Collection<Integer>);
```

Without manually creating new array instance iterating over the collection myself?

If not for collection, even for `List<Integer>` would be nice.

Comment: toArray() is the method

Comment: @Batty `toArray()` returns object array, not primitive.

Comment: @OP unfortunately no, that is one of the reasons why for instance Guava created its own implementations of primitive types collections.

Comment: About "fast", your bare-bones explicit loop solution will be as fast as it can get.

Comment: toArray() may have nulls, a primitive array not

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java

Comment: Another useful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because you must at least check how you're going to convert a null Integer to a primitive value.

Even Guava and Apache Commons have to iterate on the object list to make the conversion internally.

Guava - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29

Apache Commons - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer[]%29

Comment: Yep, I know that wrapper being null is the biggest problem here. But nothing which couldn't be done with NullPointerException. I know there  are utility libs like Apache Commons but I was interested in sdk way. Now I have confirmed there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link.. It converts the Integer List to int array ,but uses    org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils

Here is the link..

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-convert-list-of-integers-to-int-array-java-example-tips.html

Hope it helps..