# How to convert Integer[] to int[] array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, wrapper

Is there a fancy way to cast an Integer array to an int array?
(I don't want to iterate over each element; I'm looking for an elegant and quick way to write it)

The other way around I'm using

`scaleTests.add(Arrays.stream(data).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new));`

I'm looking for an one-liner but wasn't able to find something.

The goal is to:

```
int[] valuesPrimitives = <somehow cast> Integer[] valuesWrapper
```

Comment: The actual question is: why would you want to do that? The damage has already been dealt (you already created all the `Double` objects and payed with higher execution time and higher memory usage).

Comment: No you cannot cast it, as a `Double[]` is not a `double[]`. There will be an iteration behind the scenes. A one-liner could be:

    `double[] valuesPrimitives = Stream.of(valuesWrapper).mapToDouble(d -> d).toArray();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types

Comment: @Turing85, might be he just want to improve the code readability. I, as a developer assume that when I get to see huge code written by him, I can get to business logic quickly, rather than spending time on few lines of code which just does conversion part

Comment: @JavaHopper I think you misunderstood me. I see why one wants a short and elegant solution for the conversion. I do not see why one wants the actual conversion. You can simply use the `Double[]` instead of `double[]`.

Comment: @Turing85 Adapting to foreign APIs is a frequent case.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use Stream APIs of Java 8

```
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Sometimes I prefer to see `mapToInt(i -> i)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you can consider using [Apache commons ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) then there is a simple [toPrimitive](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#line.3007)  API:

> `public static double[] toPrimitive(Double[] array, double valueForNull)`
>
> Converts an array of object Doubles to primitives handling null.
>
> This method returns null for a null input array.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that I cannot use ArrayUtils. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Using Guava, you can do the following:

```
int[] intArray = Ints.toArray(intList);
```

If you're using Maven, add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groudId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Apache lang library, then you can use the ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(Integer[]) method like this:

`int[] primitiveArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(objectArray);`

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `org.apache.commons.lang3` jar file which provides `ArrayUtils` class.
Using the below line of code will solve the problem:

`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(Integer[] nonPrimitive)`

Where `nonPrimitive` is the `Integer[]` to be converted into the `int[]`.