# Integer printing wrong value

Tags: java

When converting an integer to int array, for example 123 to {1,2,3}, I am getting values {49,50,51}.
Not able to find what is wrong with my code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String temp = Integer.toString(123);
        int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i : newGuess) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 49
>
> 50
>
> 51

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an integer into an int array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482457/converting-an-integer-into-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`charAt(i)` will give you UTF-16 code unit value of the integer for example in your case, UTF-16 code unit value of 1 is 49.
To get integer representation of the value, you can **subtract '0'(UTF-16 code unit value 48)** from i.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String temp = Integer.toString(123);
        int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i : newGuess) {
            System.out.println(i - '0');
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Comment: To be pedantic, `charAt` doesn't return ASCII values, but rather `char` values, which are UTF-16 code units. It just so happens that the first 128 characters are the same either way, which covers the common Latin alphabet. But Java has never used ASCII strings, it's been Unicode from day one.

Answer (score 2):

To add a little Java 8 niceties to the mix which allows us to pack everything up neatly, you can optionally do:

```
int i = 123;
int[] nums = Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(i).split(""))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Here we get a stream to an array of strings created by splitting the string value of the given integer's numbers. We then map those into integer values with `Integer#parseInt` into an `IntStream` and then finally make that into an array.

Answer (score 1):

`temp.charAt(i)` is basically returning you characters. You need to extract the `Integer` value out of it.

You can use:

```
newGuess[i] = Character.getNumericValue(temp.charAt(i));
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
```

**Code**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String temp = Integer.toString(123);
        int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            newGuess[i] = Character.getNumericValue(temp.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int i : newGuess) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your interest is to get as an integer value of an string. Use the method parse int Integer.parseInt() . this will return as integer.
Example : 
int x =Integer.parseInt("6"); It will return integer 6.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("123")` will return integer `123`, not `{1,2,3}` int array.