# Odd numbers between 0 and 100 and add them to an array in java

Tags: java

I seen this question on Codility.
write a function:

```
class solution{ public int[] solution(int X, int Y);}
```

that given X=0 and Y=100, return an array of integers that are odd between 0 and 100.

I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 10;
    ArrayList<Integer> arrli = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int[] solution( int X, int Y){
        for(int i = X; i<=Y;i++){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
               arrli.add(i);
            }
        }return (int[])arrli.toArray();
    }
}
```

And got the below error:

```
error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to int[]
    }return (int[])arrli.toArray();
```

Comment: @softwareelceng So you seem to be struggling in how to convert your `ArrayList<Integer>` to an `int[]`. In that case [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array) has multiple answers showing different ways of doing so.

Comment: has anyone any better way of completing the above question of returning an array of integers that are odd between 0 and 100.

Comment: sure. start with the first odd one, and just add 2 each iteration, instead of checking the rest of division

Answer (score 1):

You should not use class for this solution you can just use a method to create this list.

If you are using java 8 and newer versions you can use

```
public ArrayList<Integer> createIntegerRangeWithJumps(Integer start, Integer jumpIn , Integer size){
return IntStream.iterate(start , n -> n + jumpIn).limit(size).toList();
}
```

The call `createIntegerRangeWithJumps(1,2,50)` will preduce the wanted list

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading. Your code looks correct in creating an array of odd numbers, but there are shorter codes.

With respect to the error:

```
error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to int[]
    }return (int[])arrli.toArray();
```

which I assume is you primary question:

You are creating an array of `Integer` objects, not of `int`. You can convert your Integer[] to int[]. But an easier approach is to create an array of int[] from the beginning.
For the conversion see: [How to convert Integer[] to int[] array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394715/how-to-convert-integer-to-int-array-in-java)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: now getting errors on my return statement.
import java.util.*;
public class Solution{
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 10;
    ArrayList<Integer> arrli = new ArrayList<>();
   
    public int[] solution( int X, int Y){
        for(int i = X; i<=Y;i++){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
               arrli.add(i);
            }
            int[] arr = new int[arrli.size()];
            for(int t = 0; i < arrli.size(); t++) {
             arr[t] = arrli.get(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
return arr;

Error:
Solution.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
return arr;

Comment: Check the number of opening and closing brackets. If you are using Eclipse use Command-A Command-I (source->Correct indentation) to check your code. return should be inside the function. It is outside the class!

Comment: @ChristianFries I am using a free online editor, hence i I am unable to use these tools. where do you suggest i move the return statement to.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Java 8 (assuming X and Y to be inclusive)

```
int[] oddNums = IntStream.range(X, Y+1).filter(i -> i%2 != 0).toArray();
```

Comment: Notice you are going through 100 items and you are interested only in 50 of them thats a performance issue, not a big one but the better way is to use iterate as in my answer

Comment: @Itaywazana I am just unsure how to implement this into my code..

Comment: @softwareelaceng i made my answer more detailed