# Java: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Byte[] to byte[]"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm getting this odd error in my Java and I'm completely stuck.

```
private List<byte[]> sharedWorlds = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<byte[]>());

Byte[] y = sharedWorlds.toArray(new Byte[0]);

try{

    //this line won't compile!
    Utilities.writeByteArray(outStream, sharedWorlds.toArray(new Byte[0]));

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Byte[] to byte[]

The second parameter to "writeByteArray" needs to be a byte[] and not a Byte[]...

I could loop through a new byte[] and copy every element, but this seems unclean and inefficient?

I tried casting

```
(byte[]) sharedWorlds.toArray(new Byte[0])
```

but this errors with

> Cannot cast from Byte[] to byte[]

My Java is rusty, but I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: @GalAbra: It's not really a duplicate of that IMO, as `byte` is a primitive type... it's a slightly different situation.

Comment: What's unclear to me is why you're creating a `Byte[]` at all. Why not do everything using `byte[]`?

Comment: My apologies, but try looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types)

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I tried but I couldn't do it ;( the "sharedWorlds" object is of type `List<byte[]> sharedWorlds`

Comment: Then show what you've tried, using `byte[]` everywhere, and the error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from some quick research that direct conversion isn't supported in Java.

You can use Apache Commons Lang ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[])

Or you can use a for loop to copy an object Byte array to a primitive byte array.

More info and example here [Converting an array of objects to an array of their primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types)

Comment: From looking at @GalAbra's link, I ended up using Apache Commons Lang `ArrayUtils` i.e. `Utilities.writeByteArray(outStream, ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(sharedWorlds.toArray(new Byte[0])));`

Comment: Why don't you just vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: Good point, I will delete my answer and vote to close as duplicate